# Powershell: Pipe external command output to another external command

Tags: powershell, command, pipe, external

How can I get PowerShell to understand this type of thing:

```
Robocopy.exe | Find.exe "Started"
```

The old command processor gave a result, but I'm confused about how to do this in PowerShell:

```
&robocopy | find.exe "Started"                #error
&robocopy | find.exe @("Started")             #error
&robocopy @("|", "find.exe","Started")        #error
&robocopy | &find @("Started")                #error
&(robocopy | find "Started")                  #error
```

Essentially I want to pipe the output of one external command into another external command. In reality I'll be calling flac.exe and piping it into lame.exe to convert FLAC to MP3.

Cheers

Comment: If the .exe is not designed to accept piping you cannot..

Comment: Find.exe is designed to accept piping, as is lame.exe. Any error I get is from Powershell not understanding what I mean.. You can try the Find example in cmd.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```sh
# Note the nested quoting. CAVEAT: May break in the future.
robocopy.exe | find.exe '"Started"'    

# Alternative. CAVEAT: doesn't support *variable references* after --%
robocopy.exe | find.exe --% "Started"

# *If available*, use PowerShell's equivalent of an external program.
# In lieu of `findstr.exe`, you can use Select-String (whose built-in alias is scs):
# Note: Outputs are *objects* describing the matching lines.
#       To get just the lines, pipe to | % ToString 
#       or - in PowerShell 7+ _ use -Raw
robocopy.exe | sls Started
```

For an explanation, read on.

---

**PowerShell *does* support piping to and from external programs.**

The problem here is one of parameter parsing and passing: **`find.exe`** has the curious requirement that its **search term must be enclosed in *literal* double quotes.**

In `cmd.exe`, simple double-quoting is sufficient: `find.exe "Started"`

By contrast, **PowerShell by default pre-parses parameters before passing them on and *strips* enclosing quotes** if the verbatim argument value *doesn't contain spaces*, so that `find.exe` sees only `Started`, *without the double quotes*, resulting in an error.

There are three ways to solve this:

- PS **v3+** (only an option if your parameters are only *literals* and/or *environment variables*): `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), tells PowerShell to **pass the *rest* of the command line *as-is* to the target program** (reference environment variables, if any, cmd-style (`%<var>%`)):
  `robocopy.exe | find.exe --% "Started"`

  - [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375) details the  limitations of `--%`.
- PS **v2** too, or **if you need to use PowerShell *variables* in the parameters**: apply an **outer layer of PowerShell quoting** (PowerShell will strip the single quotes and pass the contents of the string as-is to `find.exe`, with enclosing double quotes intact):
  `robocopy.exe | find.exe '"Started"'`

  - **Caveat**: It is only due to *broken behavior* that this technique works. If this behavior gets fixed (the fix may require opt-in), the above won't work anymore, because PowerShell would then pass `""Started""` behind the scenes, which breaks the call - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for more information.
- ***If an analogous *PowerShell* command is available*, use it, which avoids all quoting problems.** In this case, the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet, PowerShell's more powershell analog to `findstr.exe` can be used, as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

@Jobbo: cmd and PowerShell are two different shells. Mixing them is sometimes possible but as you realized from Shay's answer, it won't get you too far. However, you may be asking the wrong question here.

Most of the time, the problem you are trying to solve like piping to find.exe are not even necessary.
You do have equivalent of find.exe, in fact more powerful version, in Powershell: select-string

You can always run a command and assign results to a variable.

```
$results = Robocopy c:\temp\a1 c:\temp\a2 /MIR
```

Results are going to be STRING type, and you have many tools to slice and dice it.

```
PS > $results |select-string "started"

  Started : Monday, October 07, 2013 8:15:50 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

Invoke it via cmd:

```
PS> cmd /c 'Robocopy.exe | Find.exe "Started"'
```

Comment: This works, but if my commands have many parameters passed to them (which they do), then would I lose the benefits of passing parameters in an array, like @(,,,)? Is there any way to do this without involving cmd.exe?

Comment: This works, but is a nightmare to read:

&cmd @("/c",@('robocopy','|','find "Started"'))

Is it really a trade off between building it all up as one string and nesting arrays?

Comment: I know the feeling... I would write commands longer than one line in a cmd file and execute it instead.

Comment: wow that's really ragged. I wonder if I can make use of piping to Out-Host or something? I discovered I can get Robocopy's output into a Variable using Tee-Object, but then its a matter of piping a variable into an external command like: $out | &find.exe which seems just as impossible