# PowerShell JSON string escape (backslash)

Tags: json, powershell

I need to HttpPost a Json-body to a ASP.NET Core Web Api endpoint (controller) using a PowerShell script.

```
$CurrentWindowsIdentity = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$CurrentPrincipalName = $CurrentWindowsIdentity.Identity.Name

# Build JSON payload
$JsonString = @"
{
    "CurrentPrincipalName":"$CurrentPrincipalName"
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://webapiendpoint.tld/api/somecontroller" -Method Post -Body $JsonString -ContentType "application/json"
```

Since the value of the variable $CurrentPrincipalName can be domain\username, the json get's invalid because of the backslash, which is not properly escaped.

Error in the log of the web api:

```
  JSON input formatter threw an exception: 'C' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $.CurrentPrincipalName | LineNumber: 15 | BytePositionInLine: 36.
  System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'C' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $.CurrentPrincipalName
```

How can i make sure that when creating a json string and adding variables - whose values of course can not be controlled - the json string gets properly escaped?

i also tried ConvertTo-Json like:

```
$JsonConverted = $JsonString | ConvertTo-Json
```

and then HttpPost that object, but that was even worse:

```
JSON input formatter threw an exception: The JSON value could not be converted to solutionname.model. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 758.
```

Comment: As an aside re `$JsonString | ConvertTo-Json`: `ConvertTo-Json` is designed to convert _from_ hash tables or (custom) objects _to_ JSON; if you pass it something that already is a JSON string, you'll get a single JSON _string value_ (enclosed in literal double quotes), and the input object structure is lost. Try `'{ "foo": 1 }' | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The robust way to create JSON text is to **construct your data as a hash table (`@{ ... }`) or custom object ( `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`)** first and **pipe to [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json)**:

```bash
$JsonString = @{
  CurrentPrincipalName = $CurrentPrincipalName
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

That way, PowerShell performs any necessary escaping of values for you, notably including doubling the literal `\` character in your `$CurrentPrincipalName` value to ensure that it is treated as a *literal*.

Note:

- **Depending on *how deeply nested* the hashtable is, you may have to add a `-Depth` argument** to the `ConvertTo-Json` call to prevent more data from getting truncated - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) for more information.
- If you have multiple properties and want to preserve their *definition order* in the JSON representation, use an *ordered* hash table (`[ordered] @{ ... }`) or a custom object.
- In cases where the resulting JSON string is to be passed to an *external program*, in Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell (Core) up to *v7.2.x* you unfortunately have to `\`-escape all `"` characters  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

Comment: Agree. Well, partially, just hit another issue: $CurrentPrincipalIsAdmin = $CurrentWindowsIdentity.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator) needs to be $CurrentPrincipalIsAdmin = $CurrentWindowsIdentity.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator).ToString() otherwise : this: $JsonString = @{
    CurrentPrincipalIsAdmin = $CurrentPrincipalIsAdmin
} | ConvertTo-Json leads to System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'True' as a string. But this is out of scope here, would have to create a new question i think

Comment: @ChristianCasutt That's a curious error, which I would not expect - Booleans are definitely supported. If you have a reproducible case, please do post a new question, with details about your particular PowerShell version.

Comment: Try: ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1024