# Quotation marks inside Quotation marks on query string using AWS CLI (power Shell)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to do a aws query log on power shell.  But on query string part, I have quotation marks inside quotation marks, and one of that quotation mar is closing the string.
Command:

```
aws logs start-query --log-group-name /aws/containerinsights/eb21-eks-cluster/application --start-time 1618560000 --end-time 1617235200 --query-string 'fields @timestamp, kubernetes.host, kubernetes.container_name | parse @message '"log":"*"' as text | fields @message | filter kubernetes.pod_name like 'ebs-csi-' | sort @timestamp desc'
```

The problem is locate on: `'"log":"*"'`

[image: where the problem is]

Comment: You can escape quotation marks of the enclosing type by doubling them: `'Here goes ''"log":"*"'', noticed the repeated single-quotes'`

Comment: Perfect! Thank u!

Comment: Note, however, that due to a longstanding PowerShell bug you'll currently have to additionally `\ `-escape embedded `"` characters - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).