# How to escape a string to pass it to another command?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, quoting

I have an array of arguments `` $p = "a", "b c", "d`"e" `` to be passed to command.
I can do this like so:

```
& my_command $p
```

Now, I need to call that same command inside some external wrapper (binary), which works like this using fixed parameters:

```
& my_wrapper /Command=my_command "/CommandParameters=a 'b c' 'd`"e'"
```

But how can I pass the `/CommandParameters` from the array `$p`?

---

One approach that works for some inputs is to pre-process the array like so:

```
$p = $p | Foreach {"\`"$_\`""}
& my_wrapper /Command=my_command "/CommandParameters=$p"
```

but this seems pretty fragile. Values in `$p` do contain spaces and quotes.

---

In Bash, I could use `printf %q` to properly escape the parameters.

Comment: Is `my_wrapper` a binary executable or a PowerShell function?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen A binary executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following **encloses all strings in the array in embedded `"..."` and additionally escapes *preexisting* embedded `"` chars. as `\"`**, which is what external programs typically expect:

Note: **In *Windows PowerShell* and in *PowerShell (Core) up to at least v7.1*, an *additional* round of `\`-escaping is - unfortunately - needed when passing arguments with embedded `"` to *external programs***:

```sh
$p = "a", "b c", "d`"e"
$pEscaped = $p.ForEach({ '\"{0}\"' -f ($_ -replace '"', '\\\"') })
& my_wrapper /Command=my_command "/CommandParameters=$pEscaped"
```

<sup>Note: While `$pEscaped` is a *collection* (array) of strings, using it inside an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`) automatically creates a space-separated single-line representation; e.g. `"$('foo', 'bar')"` yields verbatim `foo bar`</sup>

This longstanding problem - the unexpected need for manual `\`-escaping of embedded `"` chars. when passing arguments to *external programs* - is summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

*Preview* versions of v7.2 now come with **[experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`**, which is an **attempted fix**, but, unfortunately, it looks like it will lack important accommodations for high-profile CLIs on Windows - see this summary from [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143#issuecomment-833568832). However, the fix *is* effective for executables that expect `"` to be escaped as `\"`, so the solution simplifies to (using string concatenation (`+`) inside an expression (`(...)`) to construct the argument in-line):

```sh
# Note: Requires experimental feature PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing
#       to be turned on, available in preview versions of v7.2
& my_wrapper /Command=my_command ('/CommandParameters=' + $p.ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f ($_ -replace '"', '\"') }))
```

Note:

- Assuming this experimental feature becomes an *official* one (which is in general never guaranteed), the corrected behavior will most likely be *opt-in*, via a *preference variable*: `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Standard'` (`'Legacy'` selects the old behavior).

---

If you don't mind installing a third-party module (authored by me), the [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) (`Install-Module Native`) comes with a **backward- and forward-compatible helper function, `ie`**, which too obviates the need for the extra escaping, while also containing the important accommodations for high-profile CLIs on Windows missing from the experimental feature:

```sh
# Note: Assumes `Install-Module Native` was called.
# Just use `ie` instead of `&`
ie my_wrapper /Command=my_command ('/CommandParameters=' + $p.ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f ($_ -replace '"', '\"') }))
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> [Enclosing the value in embedded `"`] seems pretty fragile

If you additionally escape any *preexisting* `"` as `\"` (`\\\"`, if the argument-passing bug must be compensated for), as shown above, it works robustly.

Ultimately, the following command line must be executed, which PowerShell constructs *behind the scenes*:

```sh
my_wrapper /Command=my_command "/CommandParameters=\"a\" \"b c\" \"d\\\"e\""
```

When `my_wrapper` parses its command line, it ends up seeing the following verbatim string as the last argument:

```
/CommandParameters="a" "b c" "d\"e"
```

> **In Bash, I could use `printf %q`** to properly escape the parameters.

Unfortunately, **PowerShell has *no* equivalent feature**, but it's not hard to provide it ad hoc:

---

#### Meta-quoting strings in Powershell:

Note:

- By *meta-quoting* I mean the functionality that Bash's `printf %q` provides: It formats a given string value to become usable as a *string literal* in *source code*. For instance (this example illustrates the general principle, not `printf %q`'s actual behavior), verbatim string value `a b` is transformed to verbatim string value `"a b"`, and the latter can be used as an argument when constructing a command line stored in a string.
- The required approach depends on whether the meta-quoted string is to be used in the string representation of a *PowerShell* command (such as a cmdlet call) or that of a call to an *external program*, given their different escaping needs. Additionally, while most external programs on Windows  (also) understand `\"` to be an escaped `"`, some - notably batch files and `msiexec.exe` - only understand `""`.

The commands below use the following sample input input string, which contains both a `'` and a `"` (constructed via a verbatim [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules?view=powershell-7.2#here-strings) for quoting convenience):

```sh
$str = @'
6'1" tall
'@
```

The solutions below use the **[`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)** to synthesize the result strings, not just for conceptual clarity, but also to **work around *string interpolation bugs*** that can cause subexpressions embedded in [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) to yield incorrect results (e.g., `"a$('""')b"` and `` "a$('`"')b" `` both yield verbatim `a"b` - one `"` / the `` ` `` is missing); an alternative is to use simple string *concatenation* with `+`.

- Unfortunately, it looks like **these bugs will *not* be fixed**, so as to preserve backward-compatibility; see [GitHub issue #3039](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3039#issuecomment-353224924)

The verbatim content of the resulting strings is shown in source-code comments, enclosed in `«...»`; e.g. `«"6'1\""»` (this representation is just for illustration; PowerShell does *not* support such delimiters).

**Meta-quoting *for external programs***:

Note:

- **On Windows, console applications typically only recognize *double* quotes as string delimiters** in their command lines, so that's what the solutions below focus on. **To create a *single*-quoted representation that is understood by POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`**, use the following:
  `"'{0}'" -f ($str -replace "'", "'\''")`, which yields verbatim `'6'\''1" tall'` (sic).
- In edge cases on Windows, you may have to *bypass* PowerShell's command-line parsing altogether, so as to fully control the command line that is used for actual process creation behind the scenes, either via `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), which has severe limitations or by delegating the invocation to `cmd.exe`, by passing an entire command line to `/c` - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

For external programs that require **`\"`-escaping** (typical):

```sh
# With the experimental, pre-v7.2 PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing
# feature turned on, you can directly pass the result
# as an external-program argument.
# Ditto with the `ie` helper function.
'"{0}"' -f ($str -replace '"', '\"') # -> «"6'1\" tall"»

# With additional \-escaping to compensate for PowerShell's
# argument-passing bug, required up to at least v7.1
'\"{0}\"' -f ($str -replace '"', '\\\"') # -> «\"6'1\\\" tall\"»
```

For external programs that require **`""`-escaping** (e.g., batch files, `msiexec` - Windows-only):

```sh
# CAVEAT: With the experimental, pre-v7.2 PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing
#         feature turned on, passing the result as an external-program argument 
#         will NOT work as intended, because \" rather than "" is invariably used.
#         By contrast, the `ie` helper function automatically
#         switches to "" for batch files, msiexec.exe and msdeploy.exe
#         and WSH scripts.
'"{0}"' -f ($str -replace '"', '""') # -> «"6'1"" tall"»

# With additional escaping to compensate for PowerShell's
# argument-passing bug, required up to at least v7.1
'""{0}""' -f ($str -replace '"', '""""') # -> «""6'1"""" tall""»
```

**Meta-quoting *for PowerShell commands***:

Note:

- Fortunately, no *extra* escaping is ever needed in this case; the argument-passing bug discussed above only affects calls to *external programs*.

**Creating a *double*-quoted representation (`"..."`)**:

```sh
'"{0}"' -f ($str -replace '"', '`"') # -> «"6'1`" tall"»
```

**Creating a *single*-quoted representation (`'...'`)**:

```sh
"'{0}'" -f ($str -replace "'", "''") # -> «'6''1" tall'»
```