# Kafka Schema Register with curl

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Command used to register schema:

```
curl -i -XPOST -u "accesskey:secretkey" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" https://schema-registry.nonprod.us-west-2.aws.proton.x.com/subjects/tracking-info-publish-avro-value/versions --data '{ "schema": "{""type"":""record"",""name"":""ShipmentNotification"",""namespace"":""com.x.ordertrackinginfo.eventschema"",""fields"":[{""name"":""sellingStoreNumber"",""type"":""int""}}'
```

Error:

> Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
> at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]curl: (6) Could not resolve host: schema
> curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 115

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer assumes that you're calling *from PowerShell* and that you're trying to *nest* JSON and that your JSON is composed as follows:

- A single, top-level `schema` property
- whose value is a *single string* that happens to contain JSON too.

If you're calling from `bash` (or similar), all you need to do is to replace all `""` with `\"` inside the `'...'` string and to insert a `"` before the final `}`.

**tl;dr**, as of PowerShell 7.1:

```sh
curl -i -XPOST -u "accesskey:secretkey" `
     -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" `
     https://schema-registry.nonprod.us-west-2.aws.proton.x.com/subjects/tracking-info-publish-avro-value/versions `
     --data (@'
      { "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ShipmentNotification\",\"namespace\":\"com.x.ordertrackinginfo.eventschema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"sellingStoreNumber\",\"type\":\"int\"}" }
'@ -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"')
```

Note the use of `` ` `` at the very end of the lines in order to continue the command on the next line (purely for readability) and that the closing `'@` delimiter must be the *very first character* on the line.

---

**Step-by-step instructions**:

**First**, create this JSON string in isolation, using a *verbatim* [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) in PowerShell (although a regular verbatim string, `'...'`, will do), with `"` characters that are part of the property *value* (as opposed to those that have *syntactic* function) escaped as `\"`, as required by JSON:

```sh
$json = @'
{ 
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ShipmentNotification\",\"namespace\":\"com.x.ordertrackinginfo.eventschema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"sellingStoreNumber\",\"type\":\"int\"}"
}
'@
```

The resulting string is valid JSON, as you can verify with `$json | ConvertFrom-Json`

**Next**, *additional* escaping must be applied in order to pass the string to an *external program*:

- Note:

  - **This extra round of escaping should never have been necessary, but is up until at least PowerShell version 7.1** (the current version as of this writing).
  - An *experimental* feature in preview versions of v7.2 can be configured to fix this, so that this step is no longer necessary.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for background information and details.

```sh
$jsonEscapedForExternalProgram = $json -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"'
```

Now you can pass the escaped JSON string to the external `curl` program (`curl.exe` on Windows):

```sh
curl -i -XPOST -u "accesskey:secretkey" `
     -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" `
     https://schema-registry.nonprod.us-west-2.aws.proton.x.com/subjects/tracking-info-publish-avro-value/versions `
     --data $jsonEscapedForExternalProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. My solution was to just use postman with the proper headers and sending a json with just the schema attribute as is explained here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#schemaregistry-api

You can use a json like this:

`{ "schema": "{ \"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"test\", \"fields\": [ { \"type\": \"string\", \"name\": \"field1\" }, { \"type\": \"int\", \"name\": \"field2\" } ] }" }`

That json was taken from the documentation.