# Convert Powershell command to curl

Tags: powershell, api, curl

I am trying make the following API calls with a curl command and run it on Linux:
https://octopus.com/blog/manually-push-build-information-to-octopus

This what I got:

```
curl -X POST https://YourServerUrl -H "X-Octopus-ApiKey"="API-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@jsonBody"
```

I am not sure how to convert this script to a json in curl

```
$jsonBody = @{
    PackageId = "twerthi/xCertificatePermission"
    Version = "1.0.0"
    OctopusBuildInformation =
        @{
            BuildEnvironment = "Jenkins"
            VcsCommitNumber = "2350881a389517288b31432d469c5c4199a1fba9"
            VcsType = "Git"
            VcsRoot = "https://github.com/twerthi/xCertificatePermission.git"
        }


   } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl command -d (--data) is the specified data in the POST request. So you should be able to just enter valid JSON data as part of the call. i.e. something like this:

```
curl -X POST https://YourServerUrl -H "X-Octopus-ApiKey"="API-XXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "PackageId":"twerthi/xCertificatePermission", "Version":"1.0.0", "OctopusBuildInformation":{ "BuildEnvironment":"Jenkins", "VcsCommitNumber":"2350881a389517288b31432d469c5c4199a1fba9", "VcsType":"Git", "VcsRoot":"https://github.com/twerthi/xCertificatePermission.git"}}'
```

Note, if you are testing this in cmd/bash etc, you can split the command over multiple lines by using an escape character. Windows: `^` Linux/MacOS: `\`

**Example in Windows:**

```
curl -X POST https://YourServerUrl ^
-H "X-Octopus-ApiKey"="API-XXX" ^
etc....
```

Also, assuming that's valid PS, you can just run it and check the result in  $jsonBody to see how its formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to call the external `curl` utility *from PowerShell* (note that on Windows, in *Windows PowerShell*, you'll have to call it as `curl.exe`):

```
curl -X POST https://YourServerUrl `
     -H 'X-Octopus-ApiKey: API-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' `
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' `
     -d ($jsonBody -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"')
```

Note the unfortunate need for a `-replace` operation on the `$jsonBody` variable containing your JSON string, which - as of PowerShell 7.1 - is needed to work around a long-standing bug, discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).