# Execute a PowerShell script within RunAs in a script

Tags: powershell, runas, powershell-7.0

I have a need to run a PowerShell script as another user (the users will actually be doing the auth) based on detected environment. The script leverages a smartcard for login. The problem I have is when the PowerShell.exe instance launches from the runas, it simply prints my command and doesn't actually run it.

Note: The filepaths have spaces that get escaped with double-`, just not shown here hence the escaped ``' in the actual command. Have also used ```".

Example:

```
Start-Process runas.exe "/netonly /smartcard /user:domain\$env:USERNAME ""powershell.exe -noexit -Command `'&$filePath -arg1 -arg2`' "" "
```

or

```
Start-Process runas.exe "/netonly /smartcard /user:domain\$env:USERNAME ""powershell.exe -noexit -File `'$filePath -arg1 -arg2`' "" "
```

File path points to the same .ps1 file. The dir is similar to: C:\Users\Username\My Documents\script.ps1

When this runs I simply get a script window that doesn't actually run, it just prints the File name. I have also tried using -File but that simply crashes (regardless of -noexit). The runas bit works fine, I get my smartcard prompt etc its just the actual PowerShell launch that I am struggling with.

These work just fine calling them directly from PowerShell Cli but when in a .ps1 it just won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's generally no reason to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to run a console application such as `runas.exe` - unless you explicitly want the application to run in a *new window*, asynchronously (by default) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for more information.

Eliminating `Start-Process` simplifies the quoting:

```
runas.exe /netonly /smartcard /user:domain\$env:USERNAME "powershell.exe -noexit -File \`"$filePath\`" -arg1 -arg2"
```

Note the - unfortunate - need to manually `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars. (`` `" ``), which is required up to at least v7.1 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

On Windows, passing a `'...'`-enclosed string to the PowerShell CLI's `-Command` (`-c`) parameter from *outside* PowerShell (such as via `runas.exe`) causes it to be interpreted as a *verbatim PowerShell string*, printing its content as-is (except for whitespace normalization).

You can verify this by running the following from `cmd.exe`, for instance:

```
C:\>powershell -c 'Get-Date; whatever I type here is used as-is -   almost'

Get-Date; whatever I type here is used as-is - almost
```

Note how the *multiple* spaces before the word `almost` were normalized to a *single* one.

The reason is that on Windows only *double*-quoting (`"..."`) has *syntactic* function on the command line - `'` characters are interpreted *verbatim* and therefore *passed through*.

Therefore, when the `-Command` (`-c`) argument sees its argument(s) -- *after* command-line parsing - and *then* interprets the resulting space-joined, possibly double-quote-stripped arguments *as PowerShell source code*, a span of `'...'` is interpreted as a verbatim PowerShell string, as usual (see the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-and-double-quoted-strings) help topic, which discusses the types of PowerShell *string literals*).

In concrete terms:

- `'Get-Date; whatever I type here is used as-is -   almost'` is parsed by the PowerShell CLI as the following arguments(!):

  - `'Get-Date;`, `whatever`, `I`, `type`, `here`, `is`, `used`, `as-is`, `-`, `almost'` - note how any information about the amount of whitespace that originally separated these argument is *lost* in the process.
- These arguments are then joined with a *single space* to form the string that PowerShell then interprets *as PowerShell source code*, which yields:

  - `'Get-Date; whatever I type here is used as-is - almost'`
- This amounts to a verbatim (single-quoted) PowerShell string literal, whose content is then output as-is.