# How do you pass an object parameter into a json arm template as a hashtable?

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

My variable is the following in powershell:

```
$lcr=@{"tierToCool"=@{"daysAfterModificationGreaterThan"=1};"tierToArchive"=@{"daysAfterModificationGreaterThan"=2}}
```

Then when I run the template using an az cli command to pass the variable as an object into my arm template:

```
az deployment group create --subscription <hidden> --resource-group <hidden> --template-file <hidden> --parameters lcr=$lcr
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to parse JSON: System.Collections.Hashtable
>
> Error Detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Is there something wrong with the way I'm passing the parameter into the template or the way I'm formatting it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `az` is expecting JSON. Try `... --parameters lcr=$($lcr |ConvertTo-Json)`

Comment: Failed to parse JSON: { Error detail: expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Comment: `--parameters` requires JSON only - either do `--parameters ($lcr|ConvertTo-Json)` or just convert your hash table to a json string manually. If 'lcr' is a parameter name too, set it as one of the hash table entries like `$lcr=@{'lcr'=@{'tierToCool'=...}}`. Check out the az group deployment page for more examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

- `az`, the Azure CLI, requires *JSON* as the `--parameters` arguments, i.e., a JSON *string*, not a *hashtable*.

  - It generally makes no sense to pass a hashtable as an argument to an *external program*, because doing so sends its *string* representation, which is - unhelpfully - the *type name*, `'System.Collections.Hashtable'`
- While `--parameters (@{ lcr = $lcr } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)` *should* be enough to send the JSON representation of your hashtable, the sad reality is that, **as of PowerShell 7.1, you additionally need to `\`-escape the embedded `"` characters**, due to a long-standing bug in argument-passing to *external programs*.

  - The most robust way to do this is (if there are no *escaped* `"` in the string, `-replace '"', '\"'` is enough):

    ```
    --parameters ((@{ lcr = $lcr } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"')
    ```
  - If you have a JSON string literal or JSON string stored in variable, use the following to pass it to an external program (if the string is stored in a variable `$var`, replace `'{ "foo": "bar" }'` with `$var`):

    ```
    someProgram ... ('{ "foo": "bar" }' -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"')
    ```
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for more information.

Therefore:

```sh
az deployment group create --subscription <hidden> --resource-group <hidden> --template-file <hidden> --parameters ((@{ lcr = $lcr } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -replace '([\\]*)"', '$1$1\"')
```

**A general [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) pitfall**: You may need to use the `-Depth` parameter for full to-JSON serialization, depending on how deeply nested your object graph is (not needed with your sample input) - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).