# mawk script works under linux, but not windows

Tags: powershell, awk

I'm trying to extract some data from a CSV file, and the command line that works under linux is not working with mawk for windows.

Using WSL, the following command works as expected:

```
    mawk -F, '$16 == "Good" {print $4}' < *GOL*_approval.txt
```

However, in powershell, the following command gives completely different results:

```
    mawk -F',' '$16 == "Good" {print $4}' *GOL*_approval.txt
```

I think it might be a quoting option, but I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output and _completely different results_ you got with that data.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- PowerShell *on Windows* doesn't support what is called *native globbing* in PowerShell (Core) on Unix-like platforms, so you must resolve your globbing (wildcard) pattern explicitly.
- Up to at least PowerShell 7.1, a long-standing bug when passing arguments to external programs that have embedded `"` characters requires them to be *manually escaped as* `\"`

  - This may finally get fixed in the upcoming v7.2 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

```
# Manual escaping of " as \" is required up to v7.1
# This may change in v7.2
mawk -F',' '$16 == \"Good\" {print $4}' (Get-Item *GOL*_approval.txt).FullName
```

Comment: GAH! That was it! I had to escape the "'s. Yeesh, that was driving me NUTS! THANK YOU!!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @SamAlleman; my pleasure. I've added a link to the answer with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of mawk? http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/mawk.htm ?

Also you are missing a `<` on the second item before the `< *GOL*_approval.txt` and putting extra `'` in `-F','`

Comment: Powershell won't let me use the "<" redirector, but it works fine without it. 
I have to quote the field separator in powershell also, for some reason.
  
I'm not really sure what version I'm using, is there an easy way to tell? 
  
I've been playing around with a reduced dataset and I am just not getting the results that I expect.

Comment: @SamAlleman, use `mawk -W version` to print the version number.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.