# Powershell - JSON string with variables as parameter

Tags: python, powershell, databricks, databricks-cli

I am trying to use Databricks CLI in PowerShell. I need to pass JSON string as parameter.

I have two variables - `job_id` equals to `10` and `parameterValue` equal to `some string`.

I used like 4 different combinations, but still getting an error of `Error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Code used:

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params "{""parameterName"":""$parameterValue""}"
```

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params "{`"parameterName`":`"$parameterValue`"}"
```

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params '{"parameterName":"$parameterValue"}'
```

Comment: the first won't work because escaping `"` is done with backtick character.
the third won't work because `$parameterValue` will not be expanded to its value when enclosed in backtick character.
Remains the second, try ``$("{`"parameterName`":`"$parameterValue`"}")`` or ``"{`"parameterName`":`"$($parameterValue)`"}"``.

Comment: "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes" .. I doubt that is the error message for all cases, because some clearly satisfy this requirement. Do you also get other errors? Have you tried a simple literal string without expansion, to narrow-down the issue?

Comment: The sad reality as of PowerShell 7.1 is that an _extra, manual_ layer of `\ `-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to _external programs_. This _may_ get fixed in 7.2, which _may_ require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad practice to try to build your own serialized strings, instead use the intended methods and [cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)  (such as [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)):

```
$job_id = 10
$parameterName = 'Some String'
$Data = @{
    job_id = $job_id
    parameterName = $parameterName
}
$Json = ConvertTo-Json $Data
databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params $Json
```

or compressed:

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params (ConvertTo-Json -Compress @{ parameterName = $parameterName })
```

Comment: Thank you, however there is still an error due to space in string `Error: Got unexpected extra argument (String
})`

Comment: This has to do with the command itself, something like `databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params "$Json"`or `databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id --notebook-params "$(ConvertTo-Json -Compress @{ parameterName = $parameterName })"` might just work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did is

1. Write python code to print passed argument

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

2. Tested this with different setups and for example:

input: `` $s="{`"parameterName`":`"$parameterValue`"}" ``

powershell output: `{"tableName":"some_string"}`

python output: `{parameterName:some_string}`

So python completely ignored the double quotes, even they were escaped.

I had to:

3. Escape ( \ ) the escape ( ` ) character:

powershell input: `` $s="{\`"parameterName\`":\`"$parameterValue\`"}" ``

powershell output: `{\"parameterName\":\"some_string\"}`

python output: `{"parameterName":"some_string"}`

The only problem I have not figured out yet is when `$parameterValue` variable includes space, then it does not work:

powershell input:

```
$parameterValue='some string'
$s="{\`"parameterName\`":\`"$parameterValue\`"}"
```

powershell output: `{\"parameterName\":\"some string\"}`

python output: `{"parameterName":"some`

Comment: The primary problem  - the unexpected need for `\ `-escaping - is on the PowerShell side (see linked duplicate). The problem with spaces must be unrelated, as something like `"{\\`"parameterName\\`": \\`"some  string\\`"}"` _does_ get seen by an external program as verbatim`{"parameterName": "some string"}`, i.e. as valid JSON, up to at least PowerShell 7.1

Comment: @romanzdk, did you ever find a solution for the space in json values ?