# Add values to an array and send it as json payload - Powershell Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I am using powershell (specifically Azure CLI) to get data from a service, add a value to a list and send a patch/post to an URL.

This is the URL to get the list of data:

```
$uriList = az rest --method get --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" --header "$header" --query spa.redirectUris | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This returns an array of strings.

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

if ($uriList -notcontains "f") {
    $uriList  += "f"
}

$uriListJSON = $uriList | ConvertTo-Json
```

Above, I have added "f" to the array and I want to send it to the url as follows:

```
$body = "{spa:{redirectUris: $uriListJSON}}"
```

az rest --method patch --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" --headers "$header" --body "$body"

I get an error:

```
Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format."
```

Please advice on what I am doing wrong. I outputted uriListJSON to a file and ran it against a json validator and it passed.

When I hardcode everything to a url like

```
az rest --method patch --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" --headers $header --body "{spa: {redirectUris: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}}"
```

it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Your from-and-to JSON conversion results in a string with - standards-compliant - embedded *double*-quoting (`"`):

```
PS> ("['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']" | ConvertFrom-Json) + 'f' | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

Since you're passing the resulting string to an ***external program*** - `az` -
the sad reality **as of PowerShell 7.2 is that an *extra, manual* layer of `\`-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required** in arguments.
This *may* get fixed in a future version, which *may* require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for details.

Therefore:

```
$uriListJSON = ("['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']" | ConvertFrom-Json) + 'f' | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$body = "{ \`"spa\`": { \`"redirectUris\`": $($uriListJSON -replace '"', '\"') } }"
```

Note that while it may not be necessary for `az`, the above uses a strictly standards-compliant JSON string in which the property names of the *verbatim* part of your JSON string too are `"..."`-quoted, which requires *both* escaping *for PowerShell* (`` `" ``) *and* manual `\`-escaping for the external program; in combination: `` \`" ``

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried it. Its not working. This is a screenshot of what I have done so far. https://imgur.com/a/WeTZCQP

Comment: @a2441918, please see my update - I hadn't noticed that the _verbatim_ part of your JSON needs`"..."` quoting and therefore `\ `-escaping too.

Comment: Tried that. Running into a string issue.  https://imgur.com/a/qWiJUVc

Comment: @a2441918: Oops! My bad: forgot to escape the embedded `"` _for PowerShell_ as well - please see my update.

Comment: Sorry. Still the issue. https://imgur.com/a/UHqgzJq Do you want me to run any additonal commands to see if the data is in the correct format?

Comment: I think I am testing the code in powershell 5, not 7.1

Comment: @a2441918 v5 vs. v7.1 shouldn't make a difference. The answer now shows you how to properly pass your JSON string to `az` (double-quoting the property _names_ may not have been necessary, but it certainly should work). You can see how an external program receives it by running `choice /d Y /t 0 /m $body` (which will additionally print `Y,N]?Y`). Since `az` is implemented as a batch file, URLs that contain `&` could break the call, but then you'd see a different error. The problem may be in the _other_ arguments you're passing to `az`, which I can't help you with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239831/discussion-between-a2441918-and-mklement0).