# Escape double ampersand in powershell script when using Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, shell, ampersand

I am trying to build a command using different strings that are created conditionally.
This command is for adding a key to vault.

Thing is, either in key description or value double ampersands can occur.
I managed to escape single ampersand, but not the two or more.
Current code, excluding parameter passing etc for brevity:

```
[string]$params = "az keyvault secret set --name `'$name`' --vault-name `'$destinationVault`' "

    if($description -ne '')
    {
        # Escaping ampersand so that it can be used in Invoke-Expression
        $params += "--description `'$($description -replace '&', '"&"')`' "
    }

    $params += "--disabled $(if($enabled) { "false" } else { "true" }) "

    if($expires -ne '')
    {
        $params += "--expires `'$(([DateTime]($expires)).ToUniversalTime().ToString($dateFormat))`' "
    }

    if($notBefore -ne '')
    {
        $params += "--not-before `'$(([DateTime]($notBefore)).ToUniversalTime().ToString($dateFormat))`' "
    }

    if($tags -ne '')
    {
        $params += "--tags `'$tags`' "
    }
    else
    {
        $params += "--tags `"`" "    
    }

    $params += "--value `'$($value -replace '&', '"&"')`'"
    
    return $params
```

Returned `params` is used by parent script - `$result = Invoke-Expression (Build-SetSecretCommand $secret $destinationKeyVault)`

Result of this code ran on example data with single `&` in secret value in console looks like that:

```
az keyvault secret set --name 'secret_name' --vault-name 'vault_name' --disabled false --tags 'file-encoding=utf-8' --value 'super_secret://+_with_symbols"&"ampersand!'
```

and translates to `super_secret://+_with_symbols&ampersand!` in created secret value.

As mentioned, code works with single `&`, but if there are more than one symbols like that, I am getting errors like

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:23
+ Write-Host asdasdasd a&&&&&asdASsdad asd a    ada   &7
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `Invoke-Expression` in the first place? (See [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).)

Comment: As an (inconsequential aside): `'` chars. inside `"..."` never require escaping (and vice versa); e.g.: `"6' tall"` (though the escaping does no harm).

Answer (score 2):

First, the obligatory warning:

- `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

In the case at hand, since you're calling an *external program* (`az`), the best approach is to create to collect the programmatically constructed arguments in an *array*, as the following simplified example demonstrates:

```sh
# Programmatically construct the arguments to pass to az below.
$azArgs = & {

  if ($description) 
  {
      '--description'
      # Enclose (runs of) ampersands (&) in arguments with *no spaces* in "..."
      # THIS MUST BE DONE FOR ALL ARGUMENTS THAT POTENTIALLY CONTAIN & 
      # such as the --value argument.
      # IF AN ARGUMENT (ALREADY) HAS EMBEDDED " CHARACTERS, MORE WORK IS NEEDED, 
      # EVEN IF IT CONTAINS SPACES - see notes below.
      if ($description -match '&' -and $description -notmatch ' ') {
        $description -replace '&+', '"$&"' 
        # NOTE: $& is a placeholder for whatever the regex matched
        #       That this placeholder also includes '&' is coincidental.
      } else {
        $description
      }
  }

  '--disabled'
  if ($enabled) { 'false' } else { 'true' }

  # ...
}

# Invoke az with the array of arguments constructed above.
az keyvault secret set --name $name --vault-name $destinationVault $azArgs
```

Note:

- The script block (`{ ... }`) outputs individual strings, which PowerShell automatically collects in an array (assuming two or more outputs).
- **`&` chars. embedded in arguments (potentially along with other `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `|`) only cause problems *if the argument contains no spaces***; this unfortunate problem is a confluence of two behaviors:

  - PowerShell - justifiably - passes space-less arguments *unquoted* on the command line *it rebuilds behind the scenes* - irrespective of the original quoting; e.g., `'a&b'` is placed as *unquoted* `a&b` on the command line ultimately used for invocation.
  - **`az` - due to being implemented *as a batch file* (`az.cmd`) - regrettably parses its command line *as if it had been invoked from inside a `cmd.exe` session***, so that an *unquoted* argument such as `a&b` *breaks* the call, because `&` is a `cmd.exe` *metacharacter*. (The problem does *not* arise if the argument happens to contain *spaces*, because PowerShell then places it *double-quoted* on the behind-the-scenes command line.)
  - While `cmd.exe` is ultimately at fault, PowerShell *could* - and arguably should - compensate for this automatically, as proposed in [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143). Sadly, it appears that this proposal won't be implemented.
- Applying embedded double-quoting to (runs of) `&` chars. in space-less arguments is *not* enough **if arguments already have embedded double quotes (`"`)**, e.g. `a"b`; in fact, preexisting embedded `"` are a problem even in arguments *with* spaces. **They require explicit escaping as `""`**, which - in contrast with the `&` issue - *is* PowerShell's fault: **passing arguments with embedded `"` has always been broken and still is as of PowerShell 7.2.1** - a possibly *opt-in* fix may come in v7.3 at the earliest - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375)

A **backward- and forward-compatible helper function that obviates the need for manual quoting and escaping** is the **`ie` function** from the [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) (`Install-Module Native`)

With the `ie` function installed, you can output the argument values *as-is* from the script block (e.g., `if ($description) { '--description'; $description }`) and simply prepend `ie`  to the invocation:

```sh
# Call via helper function "ie" from the "Native" module
# - no manual quoting / escaping needed.
ie az keyvault secret set --name $name --vault-name $destinationVault $azArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing and applying bulk of knowledge from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) excellent post, I wrote a small utility to fill my needs - to escape `"`, `&`, `|` and any combination of such characters, mostly in connection strings, etc.

```
function ConvertTo-CmdSafeString
{
    [OutputType([string])]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Source
    )
    if($Source -notmatch ' ')
    {
        $Source = $Source -replace '[\"]', '"$&'
        $Source = $Source -replace '[\"\|&]{1,}', '"$&"'
    }

    return $Source
}
```

This, given the
`$secret.value` of

```
"abc"bca""abc"""bca""""abc&abc&&abc&&&abc""||&&"abc"|&&|"|"|"|"||abc||abc|||abc&|abc|&|&abc"&abc"&|&"abc&&||abc""'"&&||""abc"''
```

It converts it to

```
""""abc""""bca""""""abc""""""""bca""""""""""abc"&"abc"&&"abc"&&&"abc"""""||&&"""abc"""|&&|""|""|""|""||"abc"||"abc"|||"abc"&|"abc"|&|&"abc"""&"abc"""&|&"""abc"&&||"abc""""""'"""&&||"""""abc""""''
```

Which after executing `$azsecret = (az $data) | ConvertFrom-Json`
gives us `$azsecret.value` of

```
"abc"bca""abc"""bca""""abc&abc&&abc&&&abc""||&&"abc"|&&|"|"|"|"||abc||abc|||abc&|abc|&|&abc"&abc"&|&"abc&&||abc""'"&&||""abc"''
```

If you see some errors in it or missed edge-cases, please let me know.

Comment: Nice, but your question doesn't imply that that preexisting embedded `"` characters also need to be dealt with. As for a robust _generic_ solution: unfortunately, more work is needed: the list of metachars. in space-less arguments that must be escaped is `& | < > ^` (spaces just used for readability) and also - if the batch file must handle arguments individually as opposed to just passing `%*` through, also `, ;`. Also, PowerShell itself is broken with respect to passing embedded `"` to external programs, also in arguments _with_ spaces; e.g., verbatim `Nat "King" Cole`

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully paint the full picture; it now includes a link to a helper function that obviates the need for all manual escaping by performing it behind the scenes.

Comment: So many issues and caveats with a very typical aplication of PowerShell script. Strange that one might need a separate module for it... But You are right - in more complicated cases aforementioned module should do the trick - my solution works for my particular usage, it's not universal - Anyway, I've ran some preliminary tests, tommorow will try said module on live organism.

Comment: I fully agree - this is much, much harder than it should be, and the current quagmire  is owed to a mix of both `cmd.exe`'s and PowerShell's "quirks". While it's understandable that `cmd.exe`, given its legacy status, wont' be fixed, it's harder to fathom in PowerShell's case - but the situation is complicated by the fact that existing workarounds would break with a proper fix. That said, even the opt-in route to a fix is headed down the wrong path; to dive down that rabbit hole, start at [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).