# Powershell curl.exe: POST request gets "400 bad request unexpected token in JSON at position..."

Tags: powershell, curl, windows-10

So I just want to make a curl (curl.exe not the basic curl on Powershell) and I'm getting this error on Powershell (Windows 10):

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2"}
```

This is my command:

```
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "username": "Code", "password": "Witcher" }' http://localhost:3000/login
```

This works on a git bash console as it is. How do you convert this to be used in a Powershell console?

Comment: The sad reality as of PowerShell 7.2.x is that an _extra, manual_ layer of `\ `-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to _external programs_. This _may_ get fixed in a future version, which _may_ require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.