# how to add quotes in this string

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this string

```
[{listenport:443,connectaddress:10.1.10.20,connectport:443,firewallrulename:port443,direction:Inbound,action:Allow,protocol:TCP},{listenport:80,connectaddress:10.1.10.20,connectport:80,firewallrulename:port80,direction:Inbound,action:Allow,protocol:TCP}]
```

i'm wondering how can I write a function to convert it to

```
[{"listenport":"443","connectaddress":"10.1.10.20","connectport":"443","firewallrulename":"port443","direction":"Inbound","action":"Allow","protocol":"TCP"},{"listenport":"80","connectaddress":"10.1.10.20","connectport":"80","firewallrulename":"port80","direction":"Inbound","action":"Allow","protocol":"TCP"}]
```

I have tried to use insert and indexof , but couldn't figure out how to do for an entire string

Comment: You're looking to write a function that can take an argument, and quote it to be read as a proper JSON object?

Comment: Where do you get the source string? That looks like malformed JSON, so fixing the source to return valid JSON might be your best bet.

Comment: hi Guys, the reason for that json input is this is used as a custom script extension, and i'm trying to pass in a arm template parameter, in order to use concat[], it has to be converted to a string from array. and even worse, when doing powershell -filelocation -parameter, it changes all the input, so it removes all the double quotes originally has. driving me crazy

Comment: If you're calling the PowerShell CLI _from PowerShell_, you may be seeing this longstanding bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375. However, you can avoid it by passing the code to execute as a _script block_ (`{ ... }`) and arguments to it via `-Args`. That said, there's rarely a good reason to call the PowerShell CLI _from inside PowerShell_.

Comment: Hi @mklement0 thanks for that, unfortunately, it is passed in from arm template, because it is a custom script extension..

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with ARM templates, but if the problem is ultimately what I suspect it is (I'm not sure), you can try to replace `"` instances with `\"` in the argument passed to the PowerShell CLI, using the [`replace` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#replace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to work with this format and cannot produce well-formed JSON to begin with, at least in your sample input both the property names and values are composed only of characters that are either `.` or fall into the `\w` regex category, so a single [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation is possible:

```
@'
[{listenport:443,connectaddress:10.1.10.20,connectport:443,firewallrulename:port443,direction:Inbound,action:Allow,protocol:TCP},{listenport:80,connectaddress:10.1.10.20,connectport:80,firewallrulename:port80,direction:Inbound,action:Allow,protocol:TCP}]
'@ -replace '[\w.]+', '"$&"'
```

The result is well-formed JSON, which you can pipe to [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) for OO processing in PowerShell.

---

If you can only assume that the property *names* are composed of only `\w` characters:

```
@'
[{listenport:443,connectaddress:10.1.10.20,connectport:443,firewallrulename:port443,direction:Inbound,action:Allow,protocol:TCP},{listenport:80,connectaddress:10.1.10.20,connectport:80,firewallrulename:port80,direction:Inbound,action:Allow,protocol:TCP}]
'@ -replace '(\w+):', '"$1":"' -replace '\}|(?<!\}),', '"$&'
```

Answer (score 0):

eventually hacked it by using replace

```
$proxyinfosjson = $proxyinfosjson.Replace(',', '","').Replace('{', '{"').Replace('}', '"}').replace(':', '":"').Replace('}"', '}').Replace('"{', '{')
```

so ugly.. not proud of it.. but works..