# How double quotes should be escaped in jq queries when PowerShell is used

Tags: windows, powershell, jq

I need to execute a [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) query which contains double quotes. I wrapped the query in single quotes, so the double quote characters should be interpreted as normal characters. Unfortunately, `jq` trims them. I don't understand how and why I should escape the double quote characters.

Example: I have the `test.json` file:

```json
{
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "name": "Foo",
      "version": "1.0",
      "licenses": [
        "GPL-1",
        "GPL-2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "bar",
      "name": "Bar",
      "version": "3.0",
      "licenses": [
        "GPL-3",
        "Apache 2.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ignored",
      "name": "Ignored",
      "version": "3.0",
      "licenses": [
        "Apache 2.0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to list all artifacts (`name` and `version`) which have at least one `GPL` licence. The result should be sorted alphabeticaly by `name`. The query to handle it is as follows:

```
[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith("GPL-"))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | "\(.name) \(.version)"
```

Unfortunately, when I execute the command it fails:

```
> cat .\test.json | jq -r '[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith("GPL-"))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | "\(.name) \(.version)"'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith(GPL-))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | \(.name)
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith(GPL-))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | \(.name)
jq: 2 compile errors
```

The error message shows that the double quote characters are missing. I tried many combinations and I finally found the correct configuration:

```
> cat .\test.json | jq -r '[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith(""GPL-""""))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | """\(.name) \(.version)""'
Bar 3.0
Foo 1.0
```

I don't understand why I should two, next four, next three and at the end two quotes.

The query works fine on Linux:

```bash
$ cat ./test.json | jq -r '[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith("GPL-"))] | uniq
ue_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | "\(.name) \(.version)"'
Bar 3.0
Foo 1.0
```

Comment: The sad reality as of PowerShell 7.2.x is that an _extra, manual_ layer of ``\``-escaping of embedded `"` characters is required in arguments passed to _external programs_. This _may_ get fixed in a future version, which _may_ require opt-in. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: To make it explicit: `jq` isn't the culprit here - it is PowerShell and the way it passes arguments with embedded `"` chars. to _any_ external program, such as `jq`.

Comment: Or run the jq filter from a file to avoid these quoting issues:  `cat file.json | jq -f jqfilter.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jq` authors recommendation is to wrap queries in double quotes on Windows when `cmd` is used. Next the double quote characters should be escaped with baskslashes (read [Invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)):

> When using the Windows command shell (cmd.exe) it's best to use double quotes around your jq program when given on the command-line (instead of the -f program-file option), but then double-quotes in the jq program need backslash escaping.

I checked with single quotes & escaping double quotes with backslashes on Windows with PowerShell. It works:

```
> cat .\test.json | jq -r '[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith(\"GPL-\"))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | \"\(.name) \(.version)\"'
Bar 3.0
Foo 1.0
```

Double quotes could be used too, but then the double quote characters must be escaped twice, for:

- jq: `"` → `\"`
- PowerShell: `"` → `""`

Required conversion: `"` → `\""`

```
> cat .\test.json | jq -r "[.artifacts[] | select(.licenses[] | startswith(\""GPL-\""))] | unique_by(.id) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | \""\(.name) \(.version)\"""
Bar 3.0
Foo 1.0
```

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375) described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/4944847) the additional escaping is required due to a bug in PowerShell.

Comment: Good summary, but it's worth pointing out that the only reason the extra ``\``-escaping is needed is due to a long-standing PowerShell bug. As an aside: `""` works perfectly fine inside `"..."`, but what you may see more frequently in practice is `\`"`, using PowerShell's general escape character, `\`` (the backtick).

Comment: The linked duplicate also shows how to automate the extra ``\``-escaping, which is convenient in general, and a necessity if your JSON string isn't a string literal you control.