# problem with closing parenthesis ')' in az rest body

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I'm trying to send a post request using az rest.
When I try send request like this - it works:

```
az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body '{"some": "Text" }'
```

but If I put ')' - closing parenthesis in body like this:

```
az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body '{"some": "Text)" }'
```

then my rest body is cut off and I receive an error:

```
az : " }" was unexpected at this time.
At line:2 char:1
+ az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body '{"some": "T ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (" }" was unexpected at this time.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

How can I escape the ')' character?

Comment: They code you've posted is clearly not the code you're running. Where did `$body` come from?

Comment: You can use ```--body @x.json``` and x.json contains json string

Comment: Are the curly bracket inside the single quotes or outside the single quotes in the PS script?  I think the curly brackets need to be place outside the single quotes.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've just fixed error message in my post

Comment: @jdweng, it is a _JSON string_ that is to be passed, so `{` and `}` should definitely _not_ go outside the single quotes. If you did that - `{'"some": "Text" '}` - you'd create a _script block_, which - due to invoking an _external program_ - gets _stringified_, in the process of which `{` and `}` are _lost_. (However, up to at least PowerShell 7.3.3 there's actually a _bug_ with respect to passing script blocks to external programs, which produces a different symptom - see [GitHub issue #10842](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10842)).

Comment: @mklement0 : This time I'm right.  See answer.

Comment: @jdweng, the solution in santal's answer - despite mistakenly crediting you - is very different from what your original comment states.

Comment: @mklement0 That's true. I misunderstood jdweng, but his answer gave me a hint how to solve it. Anyway - replacing double quotes with single quotes works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me complement your own answer with some background information:

- `'{ "some": "Text)" }'` is a *valid* JSON string (verify with `{"some": "Text)" } | ConvertFrom-Json`) and therefore *should* work.
- However, due to a **long-standing bug in how PowerShell passes arguments with *embedded `"` chars.* to *external programs*** (such as the `az` CLI), **`"` must *manually* be escaped - *typically* as `\"`, but *in this case* as `""`**.

  - As a result of the bug, embedded `"` chars. are in effect *removed*:

    - `'{ "some": "Text)" }'` becomes `"{ "some": "Text)" }"` behind the scenes, which most CLIs, including `az`, parse as verbatim `{ some: Text) }`, because - due to lack of *escaping* of the embedded `"` - *all* `"` instances are considered to have *syntactic* function and are therefore removed.
    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for details.
  - You can use `az --debug` to echo how `az` parses its arguments, which demonstrates the problem:

    ```bash
     # Note the effective loss of the " chars. in the output.
     PS> az --debug '{ "foo": "bar" }' 2>&1  | Select-String 'command arguments'

     DEBUG: cli.knack.cli: Command arguments: ['--debug', '{ foo: bar }']
    ```
- In fact, there's a dedicated [Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md) article that [`az rest` Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) link to that discusses the problems, which not only affect embedded `"` chars. but also (space-less) URLs that contain `&` (e.g. `https://example.org?foo&bar`).
- The problem with `&` is owed to the fact that **`az` is implemented *as a batch file* - `az.cmd`**. It also **the reason `""` rather than `\"` must be used for *manual* escaping** (`\"` being the most widely used syntax for escaping, with only Windows-heritage CLIs also / exclusively supporting `""`), because `cmd.exe` (the batch-file interpreter) recognizes *only* `""` as an escaped `"`, so that an argument on its process command line such as `"{ \"some\": \"Text)\" }"` *breaks* an `az.cmd` call, because the `)` is seen as *unquoted*, i.e. as having *syntactic* function, which cause a *syntax error*. By contrast, `"{ ""some"": ""Text)"" }"` works.

---

Therefore you have **two options**:

- Perform the required **manual escaping** - note the `""`:

  ```bash
  # Direct:
  az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body '{ ""some"": ""Text)"" }'

  # Indirect, using string replacement:
  az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body '{ "some": "Text)" }'.Replace('"', '""')
  ```
- ***If your target web service supports it*, *bypass* the problem** by switching to **`'`-quoting** (*single* quotes), as also shown in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75824046/45375), which isn't affected by the PowerShell bug:

  ```bash
  az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body "{ some: 'Text)' }"
  ```

  - Note that the above is - strictly speaking - *not* valid JSON, but some JSON parsers also accept JSON-*like* strings, allowing the property *names* to be *unquoted* (`some`) and allowing use of *single*-quoting in string property *values* (and also names, if needed) in lieu of the JSON-standard *double*-quoting.

    - This seems to be the case for you, and it also true for the [`Json.NET`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) parser that underlies PowerShell's [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) as of PowerShell 7.3.3.
      (`"{ some: 'Text)' }" | ConvertFrom-Json` works, for instance).
      By contrast, it does *not* work with the .NET-native [`System.Text.Json` APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) (`[System.Text.Json.JsonDocument]::Parse("{ some: 'Text)' }")` breaks, for instance)
  - The fact that you say `'{"some": "Text" }'` - with no `)` - worked even suggests that your service's JSON parser also accepts string property *values* with *no* quoting, given that `az` saw this arguments as verbatim `{some: Text }`

    - `'{"some": "Text)" }'` - *with* `)` - which PowerShell (brokenly) placed as
      `"{"some": "Text)" }"` on the `az` process command line - caused the *batch file* that the `az` is implemented as - `az.cmd` - to break, because to `cmd.exe` (the interpreter of batch files), the `)` is then *unquoted* (outside a `"..."` string), which means it has *syntactic* function, ultimately causing the *syntax error* you saw (`… was unexpected at this time`).

Answer (score 1):

Placing body in single quotes works:

```
az rest --method POST --uri "https://someaddress" --body "{'some': 'Text)' }"
```