# String parsing error while creating cloudwatch alarm via aws cli in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

When I am trying to create the cloudwatch alarms for multiple instances via powershell wth of aws cloud cli (below)

```
$instanceNames = "i-000000123456789", "i-000000123456777";

foreach ($instanceName in $instanceNames) {
    aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name 'Major Alert > Memory Usage exceeds 90%' --alarm-description 'Major Alert > Memory Usage exceeds 90%' --actions-enabled --alarm-actions 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:Test_Topic' 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456777:Test_Topic' --metric-name 'Memory % Committed Bytes In Use' --namespace 'CWAgent' --statistic 'Average' --dimensions '[{"Name":"InstanceId","Value":"'$instanceName'"}]' --period 300 --evaluation-periods 1 --datapoints-to-alarm 1 --threshold 90 --comparison-operator 'GreaterThanThreshold' --treat-missing-data 'missing'
}
```

I am getting the below error message:

> Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
> At line:4 char:1

- aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name 'Major Alert > Memory Us ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({0}"}]:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
  ```

> Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
> At line:4 char:1

- aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name 'Major Alert > Memory Us ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({0}"}]:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
  ```

Even when I am simply running the cloudwatch cli command for creating an alarm - I getting the same error for parsing the json syntax
**"Value":"'+$instanceName+'"**

Any inputs on this will be highly appreciated !!

Last part parsing error:

Sir, looking for your last assistance:
this is the verbatim string `` '[{"Name":"instance","Value":"C:"},{"Name":"InstanceId","Value":"i-0123abcxyz"},{"Name":"objectname","Value":"LogicalDisk"}]' and I have parsed it with the below one theway you showed "[{"\`Name\`":"\`instance\`","\`Value\`":"\`C:\`"},{\`"Name\`":\`"InstanceId\`",\`"Value\`":\`"'$instanceName'\`"},{"\`Name\`":"\`objectname\`","\`Value\`":"\`LogicalDisk\`"}]" but still I'm getting error. ``

Am I missing anything else here ? still it is showing incorrect format. any response on this

Comment: Replace `--dimensions '[{"Name":"InstanceId","Value":"'$instanceName'"}]'` with `--dimensions "[{""Name"":""InstanceId"",""Value"":""$instanceName""}]"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Getting below error
aws : 
At line:4 char:1
+ aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name 'Major Alert > Mem ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Error parsing parameter '--dimensions': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
JSON received: [{Name:InstanceId,Value:i-000000123456789}]

it's looking for the result to be in double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- You're trying to use *string interpolation*, yet you're using a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), in which embedded variable references such as `$instanceName` are by design *not* expanded (interpolated).

  - You **must use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) for string interpolation** (for a concise summary of the syntax and rules of PowerShell's string interpolation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)).
  - Inside such a string, any *embedded* `"` chars. must be escaped as `` `" `` or `""`.
- Due to a long-standing bug present **in *Windows PowerShell* and *[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) up to v7.2.x*, `"` characters embedded in arguments passed to *external programs* must *manually* be escaped with `\`** (note that to PowerShell itself `\` has *no* special meaning).

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375) for background information.

Therefore, formulate your `--dimensions` argument as follows:

- Up to PowerShell 7.2.x:

  ```bash
  --dimensions "[{\`"Name\`":\`"InstanceId\`",\`"Value\`":\`"$instanceName\`"}]"
  ```
- In PowerShell 7.3+ (manual `\`-escaping of `"` no longer necessary):

  ```bash
  --dimensions "[{`"Name`":`"InstanceId`",`"Value`":`"$instanceName`"}]"
  ```

For *programmatic* escaping and an alternative solution for in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x and below, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).