# Stderr and stdout for powershell with Invoke-Expression has no output or errors

Tags: powershell, stdout, stderr

I am trying to get `stdout` and `stderr` from running a java process, and saw what seemed like an easy, cool way to do it, but it did not work:

```
$command = "java -jar secretserver-jconsole.jar -s 123456 Password"
Invoke-Expression $command -OutVariable output -ErrorVariable errors
Write-Host "stdout: $output"
Write-Host "stderr: $errors"
```

Nothing displays with `$output` or `$errors`.

I am using now:

```
$output = cmd /c $command
```

This does get me some `stdout`, but it is not ideal as I want `$error` message.

I tried even this elaborate method, but it does not even seem to run the process I think as it returns almost instantly, and I know the normal process tasks several seconds.  It also shows no output or error:

```
$psi = New-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true 
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false 
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$psi.FileName = 'java' 
$psi.Arguments = @("-jar","secretserver-jconsole.jar","-
s","123456","Password") 
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
$process.StartInfo = $psi 
[void]$process.Start()
$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
$process.WaitForExit()
Write-Host "stdout: $output"
(tried: adding:
do

    $process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
}
while (!$process.HasExited)
```

Comment: Try it in PowerShell ISE. It should work the way you want.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Which of the 2 approaches, and why does running in the ISE make a difference?

Comment: @mklement0 First one. Because ISE does not have console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>Note: The solution below assumes a well-behaved external utility: one that sends *data* to *stdout*, and *error messages* to *stderr*.  If a given utility unexpectedly sends error messages to stdout instead, as appears to be the case for the OP, you must do your own parsing of stdout output in order to extract error messages.</sup>

```
$stdout = java -jar secretserver-jconsole.jar -s 123456 Password 2>($tmpFile=New-TemporaryFile)
$stderr = Get-Content $tmpFile; Remove-Item $tmpFile
```

`New-TemporaryFile` requires PSv5, but you can use `[io.path]::GetTempFileName()` in earlier versions.

Note that both `$stdout` and `$stderr` will contain a string *array*, with each item representing an output line.

The external utility's *exit code* is reflected in PowerShell's automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.

Note that capturing stdout and stderr *combined* is actually easier:

```
$stdoutAndStdErr = java -jar secretserver-jconsole.jar -s 123456 Password 2>&1
```

<sup>Note: The stderr lines are each represented as a `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instance in the result, but they evaluate to the *contents* of the line in a string context.</sup>

---

As for what you tried:

There's generally no need to store a command in a *string* (and therefore rarely a need to use `Invoke-Expression`, whose use is generally to be avoided and [can be risky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)).

- Either: invoke even external command lines directly (be mindful of possibly unwanted interpretation of the command line by PowerShell; in PSv3, [`--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), the stop-parsing token, turns off PowerShell's interpretation, but note [its limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375)).
- Or: If you need to store the full command in a variable first, use a *script block* (`$cmd = { ... }`), and invoke it later with `&` (call operator) or `.` (dot-sourcing operator) - the former creates a child scope for PS variables, the latter does not.
- Or: If you need to programmatically and conditionally construct the list of *arguments* to pass to a given external program, use an *array*, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73208537/45375).

The `-OutVariable` and `-ErrorVariable` common parameters are only designed to work with *PowerShell's* output streams, not the outside world's stdout and stderr.

- PowerShell captures stdout output as if it had been sent to PowerShell's success output stream, and treats the output lines as an *array of strings*.
- Stderr output is passed through (and is not reflected in `$Error`), but you can redirect it to a file with `2>$file`, or you can merge it into the success stream with `2>&1` (in which case the stderr lines are each represented as a `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instance).

Comment: I really hoped it would work.  I tried it running with no error, and it shows stuff in $stdout, but if I purposely make it fail it shows stderr on $stdout.  That may be the jar so I tried something different where command was a simple dir c:\temp which showed stuff on $stdout, and then I did command dir c:\temp2 (does not exist), and it did correctly show on stderr.  I will have to parse the stdout it looks like to look for something to indicate it is an error unfortunately.    Thanks for the clarification though on the various pieces about ., &, -OutVariable/-ErrorVariable, etc.

Comment: @user372429: So the jar is ill-behaved in that it sends its error messages to stdout instead of to stderr? If that's the case, and you agree that the approach presented in this answer does work for well-behaved utilities, I still suggest you accept this answer to provide guidance to future readers.

Comment: Absolutely, the answer is sound for most cases, but the jar file is not sending errors to stderr it appears.  I suppose I could try and find what logger it uses or contact the vendor and ask them to update, but I do not suspect they would be particularly expedient in their response.  Thanks you again so much for the information.  I went ahead and marked it as a good answer regardless.

Comment: @user372429: I appreciate it; definitely worth giving the vendor feedback.