# dotnet ef scaffold Unrecognized option '-t firstTable -t secondTable' - pass arguments stored in a string

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, programmatically-created

I have a .ps1 file that I run from PowerShell, the code is as follows:

```
$strTables = ""
$tables | ForEach-Object{            
    $strTables += "-t $_ "  
}
# $strTables = -t fisrtTable -t secondTable
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold $strConn Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --context MyModel $strTables -v -f
```

If I put the variable `$strTable` in the command it does not recognise the `-t` parameter (but the variable `$strConn` does work)

```
Unrecognized option '-t fisrtTable -t secondTable'
```

If I write the tables without the variable, it works.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold $strConn Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --context MyModel -t firstTable -t secondTable -v -f
```

I have too many tables to do this manually. Do you know how I can concatenate variable `$strTables` with the `dotnet` command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to with C#, .NET or Entity Framework, it's entirely PowerShell. You need to use `Invoke-Expression` if you want to execute a command line from a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338015/how-do-you-execute-an-arbitrary-native-command-from-a-string

Comment: I tried @davidg and it works too

Comment: @DavidG, while `Invoke-Expression` technically works, it is generally [best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), as there are usually superior - and safer - alternatives. Indeed, constructing the arguments as individual elements of an _array_ is the preferable solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you construct a **string such as `-t foo`** and pass it via a variable to an **external program**, it is passed as a *single*, double-quoted argument (that is, **`donet` will literally see `"-t foo"` on its command line**) - and therefore won't be recognized as parameter name-value combination.

- You must **pass `-t` and `foo` *separately***, as **elements of an *array*** instead.
- When you use an array as an argument for an external program, PowerShell passes the array elements as *individual, space-separated arguments*:

```bash
# Create an array such as '-t', 'foo', '-t', 'bar', ...
$tableArgs = 
  $tables | ForEach-Object{            
    '-t', "$_"  
  }

# Note the use of $tableArgs as-is, which causes PowerShell to pass
# e.g. ... -t foo -t bar ... behind the scenes.
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold $strConn Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --context MyModel $tableArgs -v -f
```

To provide a simpler example: The equivalent of `foo -s -o "bar baz" file1` is:

```bash
$a = '-s', '-o', 'bar baz', 'file1'; foo $a
```

As the first code snippet implies, you're free to *mix* explicitly specified arguments with those provided via an array.

---

As an aside:

- If the array containing the argument is stored in a *variable*, you may alternatively use [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), i.e yo may pass `@tableArgs` (`@` instead of `$`). However, given that with external programs and arrays this is the same as passing an array (variable) directly, there is no advantage in doing so.
- However, splatting *is* necessary in order to pass programmatically constructed arguments to *PowerShell* commands, where it is more commonly based on a *hashtable* whose keys identify the target parameters, which enables passing *named* arguments.