# Unknown hostname error when running SCP from Powershell script

Tags: powershell, winscp

I am trying to write a Powershell script that copies files from a Windows PC to a Linux box.

I am able to SSH into my remote Linux machine from a Powershell window using SSH keys (stored in `%userprofile%/.ssh/` on the Windows machine. I can also run an SCP command from the terminal window copying files from the Windows machine to the Linux box.

However, the very same `scp` command fails when run from a script (`script.ps1`) with the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <hostname>: No such host is known.
lost connection
```

Anyone know why `scp` cannot resolve the hostname when run as a script in Powershell, when it can from the terminal?

The scp command I am running looks like:

```
& C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe -r 'bin/release/net7.0/linux-x64/publish' <user_name>@<comp_name>:/home/<user_name>/containers/net_ws/app
```

---

As an aside, I tried to ping the `<comp_name>` from within the same script and it pings successfully, so there appears to be no issue resolving the `comp_name` host within the powershell context.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose the problem. I wouldn't expect it to make a difference, but to ensure that your target path isn't subject to potentially unwanted interpretation, enclose it in `'...'` too. If you need _string interpolation_, use `"..."`

Comment: The hostname is being resolved on the local machine and not the remote machine.  When you type the command in a terminal it is being executed on the remote machine.  You are passing a string command to the remote machine.  Put entire arguments in a variable surrounded by single quotes so there is no substitution in PS.  Also use two sets of single quotes around the single quotes. : $arguments = '-r ''bin/release/net7.0/linux-x64/publish''  <user_name>@<comp_name>:/home/<user_name>/containers/net_ws/app'  then : & C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe $arguments.

Comment: I've tried a number of different combinations of " and 's as I was wondering if I was running into string interpolation issues. @mklement0, can you suggest further information I can provide?

Comment: @jdweng, you can _not_ use a _single string_ to encode _multiple_ arguments with direct invocation (possibly via `&`) - see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73208537/45375). Please consider deleting your comment.

Comment: FYI, I've managed to make the script work by renaming the `<comp_name>` to it's IP address. In this case, it's something specifically around how `scp` is trying to resolve the IP address.

Comment: @mklement0 : You are not send arguments.  You are sending a command string to a remote device.  The -r should not of been part of the arguments since it doesn't get sent to the remove device.

Comment: @jdweng, multiple arguments must be passed to `sdp.exe`, _locally_, as shown in the question. They cannot be passed _as a single string_ as suggested in your first comment (maybe your'e thinking of `ssh`, not `scp`). To pass multiple arguments _programmatically_ to an external program, use an _array_, as discussed in the previous answer I mentioned. Please consider deleting your comments, as they are irrelevant to the question and suggest an approach that cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thought full explanation is lacking.

I have solved the script issue by replacing the `comp_name` with the ip address of the device.

```
& C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe -r 'bin/release/net7.0/linux-x64/publish' 
<user_name>@<ip_address>:/home/<user_name>/containers/net_ws/app
```

I'm still curious as to why scp is unable to resolve the ip address from the host name in this instance - i.e. when running as part of a script, rather than in the terminal, especially since other executables running in the same script context are able to find the host.