# If I start a process in Powershell using Start-Process, how can I check that it has finished

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, start-process

I have a script to process videos, in which I first start a download and then video conversion. The purpose of conversion is not to change container format but to clean up video frames downloaded, reduce audio from 2 channels to one etc.

Both steps take some time, so I thought I could use a kind of parallel processing. The download would run with -Wait parameter, while the conversion would be started in another window,running in parallel. Something like this:

```
$files_to_process |
  ForEach-Object {

    <# check if $conversion started in previous cycle iteration 
       has already finished or else wait #>

    <# prepare some parameters from the object #>

    Start-Process yt-dlp -ArgumentList $ytdlp_args -Wait -NoNewWindow
    $conversion = Start-Process ffmpeg -ArgumentList $ff_args
  }
```

However, the conversion takes longer than the download, so if I want to process a larger list of videos, without control I would end up with ffmpeg processes taking all CPU and memory before the list could be finished.

I was trying to find out if I can get any useful information from the object returned by calling Start-Process, it does not seem to be even mentioned in the microsoft docs for Start-Process, in some example I could only see there is a property called "Id"

There is a function `Get-Process -Id $id` but it does not return any information whether the process is running or has finished.

How can I manage this? The same issue applies to other scenarios, e.g. for downloading data by Invoke-WebRequest and then processing them and writing into a database, where, in some cases, there could also appear this kind of timing issue.

Comment: The Id you get back can be used with `Wait-Process`

Comment: Maybe investigate Start-Job

Comment: @Civette I thought so, however with Start-Job starting a script block containing Start-Process I am getting weird results - all jobs seem to be completed, even one second after start, even when I use Start-Proces ffmpeg -Wait inside the block. I am unable to obtain reasonable information from Get-Job result. 
I tried another approach and it sort of works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

[Your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77315603/45375) is a *custom* implementation for ***throttling* parallelism**, i.e. for **ensuring that no more than N operations run in parallel at a time**.

- With [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), a custom implementation is indeed required, and the same goes for [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job).
- However, the **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)** cmdlet and the ***PowerShell (Core) 7+* `-Parallel` feature of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** have this **ability *built in***:

  - Both mechanisms are *thread*-based (whereas `Start-Job` heavy-handedly uses *child processes* and has *no* throttling mechanism) and throttle ***by default***, allowing **at most `5` threads** to run at a given time, and offer a **`-ThrottleLimit` parameter** (for CPU-bound operations, it's best not to exceed the number of available CPU cores).
  - As an aside: If `Start-ThreadJob` is available - *by default* in PowerShell (Core) 7+ and *installable on demand* in Windows PowerShell (see below), it is almost always the better choice than `Start-Job` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375) for background.

---

Therefore, you can use either of these mechanism with *synchronous* calls, and let `-ThrottleLimit 2` ensure that the parallelism is throttled as desired:

- If you're running *Windows PowerShell*, you can install `Start-ThreadJob` [from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob), e.g. with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob`, which then enables the following solution:

  ```
  $files_to_process | 
    ForEach-Object {
      Start-ThreadJob -ThrottleLimit 2 {
        $filePath = ($using:_).FullName
        Start-Process -Wait step1 -ArgumentList $step1args  -NoNewWindow
        Start-Process -Wait step2 -ArgumentList $step2args
      }
    } |
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
  ```
- If you're running [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the solution is much simpler, via `ForEach-Object -Parallel`:

  ```
  $files_to_process | 
    ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 2 -Parallel {
      $filePath = ($using:_).FullName
      Start-Process -Wait step1 -ArgumentList $step1args  -NoNewWindow
      Start-Process -Wait step2 -ArgumentList $step2args
    }
  ```

Note:

- If what you're invoking are *console* applications, you don't need [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with `-Wait`, and can simply invoke them *directly* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) for background.
- More work is needed if you want to check the *exit codes* of the child processes launched, namely in the form of *outputting* them and making the caller collect and analyze them.

Comment: I used Start-Process namely because I can prepare whatever combination of command line parameters (dynamic) into a string and then just pass it as -ArgumentList. I have other scripts, which, for instance, read time segments to be cut off from a video (skip) and those can differ from file to file, including number of segments to cut out. From that point of view Start-Process provides the needed versatility.

Comment: I see, @JindrichVavruska. But note that with direct invocation you can simply prepare your arguments in an _array_, with each parameter (option) name and parameter value / positional argument (operand) becoming its own element. E.g., to execute `foo -o "bar baz"`, use `$a = '-o', 'bar baz'; foo $a`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73208537/45375) for details.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I tried this:

```
$processList = @()
$files_to_process | ForEach-Object {
  while( $processList.Count -ge 2 ) {
    $pending, [array]$other = $processList
    Wait-Process -Id $pending
    $processList = $other
  }
  <# parameter preparation into $step1args, $step2args #>
  Start-Process step1 -ArgumentList $step1args -Wait -NoNewWindow
  $p = Start-Process step2 -ArgumentList $step2args -PassThru
  $processList += $p.Id
}
```

and it works.

It is specific for the workflow I use in this use case but could be used in similar situations.

Answer (score -1):

If it would be sufficient to process the downloaded files one by one, you could do it like follows:

```
$files_to_process | ForEach-Object {

    <# check if $conversion started in previous cycle iteration 
       has already finished or else wait #>
    If ($ytdlpproc.HasExited -ne $true -or $ffmpegproc.HasExited -ne $true) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }

    <# prepare some parameters from the object #>

    $ytdlpproc = Start-Process yt-dlp -ArgumentList $ytdlp_args -NoNewWindow -PassThru
    Wait-Process -InputObject $ytdlpproc

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    $ffmpegproc = Start-Process ffmpeg -ArgumentList $ff_args -PassThru
    Wait-Process -InputObject $ffmpegproc 
}
```

There is a caveat when using Wait-Process with bootstrapper executables. Some of them kill themselves as soon as they have started the main gui for the application.

Comment: If synchronous one-by-one processing is acceptable, all you need is to use `-Wait` in _both_ `Start-Process` calls, in which case you neither need the brittle `Start-Sleep` approach nor separate `Wait-Process` calls.

Comment: @mklement0 To be clear: what I meant with bootstrapper executables is the behaviour of some executables, which just handle the startup, load the other programs and libs in memory and kill themselves, so that the child processes take over. The meanest of all I encountered personally was a nullsoft uninstaller, which just started up, placed some windows api calls for the uninstallation, and then killed itself within millisecons. Even with childprocess detection it was not manageable using wait-process or start-process -wait. Start-Sleep helped but it was ugly for sure.

Comment: Understood, but that means that (a) you're solving a different problem than what this question is about and (b)  you're not framing your answer accordingly. The OP's own answer implies that `Wait-Process` is sufficient and, therefore, with one-at-a time processing, so is `Start-Process -Wait`. `Start-Process -Wait` actually _does_ track child processes, unlike `Wait-Process` (but, as you note, even that isn't always enough) - see [GitHub issue #15555](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15555).

Comment: When child-process tracking isn't enough, it still makes sense to use `Start-Process -Wait` to at least wait
until the initial process and its children have exited (no need for a separate `Wait-Process` call, which wouldn't track children).
And `Start-Sleep` _alone_ is obviously brittle; a robust solution would require a polling loop with periodic sleeps in which the
completion of the task can be _inferred_ from changes in the environment.

Comment: I other words, you have to know what those kind of applications have on their schedule and write a custom script observing this schedule. imho impossible for most end user applications only uninstallers could be tracked like tghis. Indeed it would be much better to repackage this kind of uninstallers or write a custom uninstallation / scrub script, as the target state is clearly known.