# Are all CMD commands available within powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

Similar to other questions, but are ALL CMD commands usable within Powershell? In short, can I use a Powershell window to supplant CMD prompts, and do both CMD work and Powershell work in the same terminal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those **commands that are *built into* `cmd.exe`** (e.g., `dir`, `type`) are  ***not directly* callable** in a PowerShell session, but you can **call them via `cmd /c ...`**; e.g.:

```bash
# From PowerShell; calls the cmd.exe-internal `ver` command.
cmd /c ver
```

However, you'll find that **most such commands have more powerful PowerShell counterparts.**
To ease the transition, some PowerShell commands (called *cmdlets*) have *aliases* named for their `cmd.exe` predecessors (e.g., `dir` is aliased to `Get-ChildItem`; use `Get-Command <name>` to find out what command a given name refers to).

Note that **PowerShell also provides superior replacements for *external* utilities**; e.g., PowerShell's `Select-String` is a superior alternative to `findstr.exe`.
Unlike the built-in `cmd.exe` commands, **you can invoke such external utilities *directly* from PowerShell**.

You can **run `where.exe <name>` to determine whether a given command name refers to a built-in `cmd.exe` command or an external utility**: if it is the latter, its full path is printed.
(This technique works from both `cmd.exe` and `PowerShell`, but in PowerShell you must include the `.exe` extension, because just `where` means something different: it is an alias of the `Where-Object` cmdlet.)

In all these cases it's important to understand that **PowerShell syntax works very differently** and that **the arguments you pass will be interpreted by PowerShell *first***:

- [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) provides a **high-level overview**.
- Notably, **PowerShell has many more metacharacters than `cmd.exe`** (more characters have special syntactical meaning).
- Of particular interest when calling `cmd /c` or invoking an external utility is the PSv3+ ***stop-parsing*  token, [`--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), which treats the remainder of the command as if it had been invoked from `cmd.exe`**; e.g.:
  `cmd /c --% echo %windir%`

  - *Caveat*: `--%` has many limitations and pitfalls - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kind of.

Powershell sometimes use different syntax for the commands, so if you have specific commands you often use in CMD, you might want to do a quick search for those first. *Most* commands are the same though. Be aware that a bunch of powershell commands can't be run without the window having admin privileges, and a PS window does not guarantee that it has those privileges.

The new update to Windows 10 did away with normal CMD windows in favor of PS. This does mean that it shows up electric blue, but you can always change that using the options in Defaults or Properties. I believe this change in Win10 also meant they set aliases for CMD within PS for us, but don't quote me on that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cmd` command, it converts a PowerShell session to a Command Prompt session.

Also, if you need Powershell or Command prompt commands, you can switch back and forth in either interface by typing `powershell` and `cmd`, respectively.