# Supplying an input file via '@' gives an error: The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression

Tags: powershell, escaping, az

Following this example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest

I'm getting an error when running my command

```
az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name win-vm -g my-resource-group --scripts @script.ps1
```

Error:

> The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@script' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$script'.

Putting it in quotes only passes in the contents in the quotes, not the contents of the script.

Comment: How does this work with a variable, e.g. `$file="script.ps1"`? `@$file` Just literally prints "@$File"

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, just don't include any quotes, i.e. `@$File` works.

Comment: tl;dr: While `@$File` happens to work, it _shouldn't be relied upon_, given that it breaks if `@` is followed by a _literal_ value, as in your question. Use `\`@$File` / `\`@script.ps1` or `"@$File"` / `'@script.ps1'`. Alternatively, to pass everything through as-is, without the ability to reference PowerShell variables, use `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)

Answer (score 28):

if you install package whit @ you should install package with CMD

Comment: Well, this works well for npm or yarn libraries but you need to include more information about how or why it works or alternatively provide some source of information. Please do not post a solution without any reason as to why it works.

Comment: @r.ansarirad Thanks for the tip. works great. please keep posting any clue regardless of what people say. Help in any measure is always appriciated.

Answer (score 11):

Note:

- This answer shows **how to *escape / quote* the `@` char. properly** in the context of PowerShell's usual parsing rules.
- If your **command line only contains *verbatim* arguments** - i.e., only literal tokens, not PowerShell *variable references* (e.g, `$file`) or *expressions* (e.g., `($dir + '\script.ps1')`) - you can **alternatively place `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), before the pass-through arguments**, as shown in [programmer365's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59811539/45375); note that `cmd.exe`-style variable references such as `%FOO%` are still expanded, however, and that the stop-parsing token has many limitations and pitfalls - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

---

**`@` is a *metacharacter* in PowerShell** (a character with syntactic meaning<sup>[1]</sup>), so in order to pass it *verbatim* through to `az` you must either **quote the whole argument or `` ` ``-escape the `@` individually**:

With a *literal* script filename:

```sh
# Either: `-escape the @
az ... --scripts `@script.ps1

#`# Or: quote the whole argument
# Use '...' for a literal argument.
az ... --scripts '@script.ps1'
```

With the script filename stored in a *variable*, `$file`:

```sh
# Either: `-escape the @
az ... --scripts `@$file

#`# Or: quote the whole argument
# Use "..." for an argument with variable references, i.e. an expandable string
az ... --scripts "@$file"
```

Note: You *could* get away with just `@$file` in the variable case, but given that that doesn't work with any char. *other* than `$` following the `@`, it's better to get into the habit of always quoting / escaping a verbatim `@`.

---

<sup>[1] `@` has several syntactic uses, and the specific use depends on what character comes next. In your case, the `@` in `@script.ps1` was interpreted as the [splatting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) with a variable named `script`, with the `.ps1` part interpreted as an attempt to access a property named `ps1` on that variable - hence the error message.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
az --% vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name win-vm -g my-resource-group --scripts @script.ps1
```

In PowerShell the special Stop Parsing symbol `--%` is a signal to PowerShell to stop interpreting any remaining characters on the line. This can be used to call a non-PowerShell utility and pass along some quoted parameters exactly as is.