# Using az vm run-command from within a .ps1 script and with .ps1 script file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have created a VM in Azure, and I can run the following command from my local Windows 10 Powershell window:

`az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --resource-group $ResourceGroup --name $AD1Name --scripts "@provision.ps1"`

But when I put this line in a Powershell script file, CreateVMAndProvision.ps1, and run my CreateVMAndProvision.ps1 that also run the `az vm create...` I get the following error:

```
  "value": [
    {
      "code": "ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "",
      "time": null
    },
    {
      "code": "ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "message": "At C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\1.1.5\\Downloads\\script6.ps1:1 char:1
+ @provision.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@provision'
can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use
'$provision'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
 ",
      "time": null
    }
  ]
}
```

The syntax of specifying my local provision.ps1 file to the az cli command as `"@provision.ps1"` seem to be the problem, but I can not figure out how to solve this. I have tried to use double quotes, combination of double and single quotes, here string (@"..."@) and (@'...'@) without any success.

Anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!
:: Petter

Comment: So you're trying to escape the @?
if so, try this ```--scripts "`@provision.ps1"```
That is a backtick ` before the @.

Comment: Same output, and with --scripts '`@provision.ps1', the output is that the @provision.ps1 is not a known cmd, i.e. that it is not taking the script in my directory, but rather trying to run @provision.ps1 as a command on the guest OS.

Comment: Please check if the solutions listed here work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805670/supplying-an-input-file-via-gives-an-error-the-splatting-operator-canno

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one of the [Quoting issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?view=azure-cli-latest#quoting-issues) documented in the Azure CLI docs:

> When running Azure CLI commands in PowerShell, parsing errors will
> occur when the arguments contain special characters of PowerShell,
> such as at `@`. You can solve this problem by adding a backtick (`)
> before the special character to escape it, or by enclosing the
> argument with single or double quotes '/".
>
> For example, `az group deployment create --parameters @parameters.json`
> doesn't work in PowerShell because `@` is parsed as a [splatting symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7).
> To fix this, you may change the argument to `@parameters.json or
> '@parameters.json'.

Since what you have is a PS script already, the easiest way out would be to use the PowerShell equivalent of `az vm run-command`, which is [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-4.7.0).

Here is how you can use it:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

Other ways to run PowerShell scripts in your Windows VM by using Run Command are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command).

But if you do have specific reasons to use Azure CLI commands within your PS script, you could also try using PowerShell's **stop-parsing symbol** `--%` in your command. The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in PowerShell 3.0, directs PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as PowerShell commands or expressions.

So this should do the trick:

```
az --% vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --resource-group '<myResourceGroup>' --name '<myVMName>' --scripts @script.ps1
```