# Difference when executing Java command via CMD vs Powershell - caused by periods (".")

Tags: java, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've got an example Java application that requires an HTTP Proxy to be specified in some environments.

When I try running this using the argument as suggested on the [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) in CMD (Command Prompt) it works fine.

```
E:\>java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com -jar myJAR.jar
System properties...
[...]
http.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com
```

You can see that the application has been run, and when listing the system properties it's correctly received the `http.proxyHost` property.

However, when I run this from Powershell, I get the following:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\> java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com -jar myJAR.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class .proxyHost=http:..proxy.example.com
```

Here it appears some kind of breaking has occurred around the first "." and from then on it's treated the rest as another argument.

If the argument is quoted - e.g. `-D"http.proxyHost"=http://proxy.example.com` - then it works fine in Powershell.

Can anyone explain this behavior, please?

Comment: Powershell will try to parse your input parameters to the program so to avoid that you need to wrap them in double quotes so that instead of parsing them they are passed as it is to the executable program

Comment: @DevX do you have a source for this, please?

Comment: See [Call Operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) for how to call external programs from PowerShell.

Comment: @Jakg I did some search a while back when I had the same problem with java and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/731638/command-line-parameters-in-powershell) on SuperUser. May not be an exact source you were looking for but it did help me understand a few things

Comment: The comment from @AdminofThings is the answer.  The Call Operator prevents inappropriate parsing of the arguments to java.

Comment: @Jakg, see [About Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7) and [Command Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax?view=powershell-7).  `-` tells PowerShell a parameter is coming and everything after it is treated as an expandable string. `.` is the member access operator in PowerShell. So it needs to be escaped or you need to tell Posh to stop parsing --> `java --% -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com -jar myJAR.jar`

Comment: @Jakg, also, the fact that you started your execution line with `java`, PowerShell goes into argument parsing mode. You can see on the links I provided examples of when the different parsing modes are activated.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, while `--%` is an effective _workaround_ - albeit one with major side effects in general - the behavior is a _bug_: since the unquoted token isn't a variable reference or expression, it should be treated like an _expandable string_ - `.` should have _no_ special meaning in this context; a side-effect-free workaround is to quote the `.` individually as `'.'`

Comment: No, @WalterMitty: whether or not you use `&` (the call operator) makes no difference with respect to argument parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **you're seeing a *bug* in PowerShell**, present up to at least v7.3.6 (current as of this writing):

Something that looks like a parameter *to PowerShell* is broken into *two* arguments at the `.` (period) - even though the argument should simply be *passed through*, given that an external program is called - see [GitHub issue #6291](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291); in your case, `-Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com` is unexpectedly passed as
`-Dhttp .proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com` (note the space before the `.`)

**Workarounds**:

- `` ` ``-escape the initial `-` (or *quote* the `.` character individually (`'.'`) or quote the *whole* argument):

  ```
  java `-Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com -jar myJAR.jar
  ```
- Alternatively, as shown in [Sergey Shu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490721/45375), use `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), to force PowerShell to pass all arguments through without applying PowerShell's usual parsing rules.

  - **Caveat**: **Use of `--%` has major side effects**, notably the inability to use *variable references* in the command and the inability to apply *redirections* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375) for details.

Answer (score 1):

man about_Parsing

try running from powershell using --% parameter:

```
java --% -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.example.com -jar myJAR.jar
```