# How can I solve this I suppose a MS PowerShell parsing error?

Tags: mongodb, powershell, heroku, syntax, parameter-passing

When I used the command below [1] to set my configuration variable MONGODB_URI, it gives an error [2].
I am using Windows PowerShell.

[1] >> `heroku config:set MONGODB_URI='mongodb+srv://myprojectname:<mypassword>@cluster0.rkitj.mongodb.net/<myusername>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`

[2] The system cannot find the file specified.
'w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Note: `myprojectname`, `mypassword` and `myusername` are placeholders for the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `heroku` CLI entry point is a *batch file*, as implied by the wording of the error messages, which are `cmd.exe`'s, not PowerShell's.

PowerShell doesn't take the special parsing needs of batch files (`cmd.exe`) into account when it synthesizes the actual command line to use behind the scenes, which involves *re-quoting*, using *double* quotes only, and only when PowerShell thinks quoting is *needed*.

In this case PowerShell does *not* double-quote (because the value contains no *spaces*), which breaks the batch-file invocation.

You have the following options:

- You can **use *embedded* quoting** so as to ensure that the value part of your `MONGODB_URI=...` key-value pair is passed in double quotes; note the `'"..."'` quoting:

  ```
  heroku config:set MONGODB_URI='"mongodb+srv://myprojectname:<mypassword>@cluster0.rkitj.mongodb.net/<myusername>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"'
  ```

  - **Caveat**: This *shouldn't* work, and currently only works because PowerShell's passing of arguments to external program is fundamentally broken as of PowerShell 7.1 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375). Should this ever get fixed, the above will break.
- **If your command line doesn't involve any *PowerShell* variables and expressions**, you can use **`--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)**, which, however, in general, has many limitations (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375)); essentially, everything after `--%` is copied *verbatim* to the target command line, except for expanding `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references (e.g., `%USERNAME%`):

  ```
  heroku config:set --% MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://myprojectname:<mypassword>@cluster0.rkitj.mongodb.net/<myusername>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  ```
- If you're willing to install a module, you can **use the `ie` function** from the **PSv3+ [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)** (install with `Install-Module Native` from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Native) in PSv5+), which internally **compensates for all of PowerShell's argument-passing and `cmd.exe`'s argument-parsing quirks** (it is implemented in a forward-compatible manner so that should PowerShell itself ever get fixed, the function will simply defer to PowerShell); that way, you can simply focus on meeting *PowerShell*'s syntax requirements, and let `ie` handle the rest:

  ```
  # 'ie' prepended to an invocation that uses only PowerShell syntax
  ie heroku config:set MONGODB_URI='mongodb+srv://myprojectname:<mypassword>@cluster0.rkitj.mongodb.net/<myusername>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
  ```

Comment: Why did I click the links? Wow what a rabbit hole. Very informative though.

Comment: Using embedded quoting solved the problem. thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Kimley; my pleasure.