# Powershell use Read-Host variables in command

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a very simple .ps1-script:

```
$prename = Read-Host 'What is your prename?'
$lastname = Read-Host 'What is your lastname?'
.\migration.exe -name=$prename -password=$lastname
```

Regardless of what the user enters, $prename and $lastname don't get passed to migration.exe - they are empty!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $prename and $lastname don't get passed to migration.exe - they are empty!

These variable references are *not* empty; **they're - unexpectedly - *not expanded* (interpolated)**, as of PowerShell 7.1; that is, external program `.\migration` unexpectedly receives the following arguments *verbatim*: `-name=$prename` and `-password=$lastname`.

**This should be considered a *bug*** - see [GitHub issue #14587](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14587).

The **workaround** is to use explicit [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`):

```
.\migration.exe -name="$prename" -password="$lastname"
```

Note: On Windows, the partial quoting is *not* guaranteed to be passed through *as-is* to the target program; instead, PowerShell performs its own parsing first and then performs (`"`-based) *re-quoting on demand* behind the scenes, depending on whether the resulting argument contains *whitespace*. For instance, if `$prename`'s value is `foo`,
verbatim `-name=foo` is passed to `migration.exe`; if the value is `foo bar`,
verbatim `"-name=foo bar"` is passed - which the target program may or may not process properly; if not, you'll have to use `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the objects $prename and $lastname.  You need expand the variables so you pass the value in the variables.

```
.\migration.exe -name=$($prename) -password=$($lastname)
```

Comment: The OP's command should work as-is, and the fact that it doesn't should be considered a bug. The use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), should neither be required nor make a difference. While it unexpectedly does make a difference here, it is _not_ a viable workaround - it malfunctions too, albeit differently.