# Issue with ) when using Azure CLI to set Azure Function app Configurations

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-cli

I published an app using Azure CLI with command

```
func azure functionapp publish [my-app-name] --nozip
```

Now I want to update the configuration of the app to connect to the Azure Key Vault and get secrets from the Vault. So, I am running this command

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name [my-app-name] --resource-group [my-app-res-group] --settings "PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name])"
```

this returns an error like this

```
request failed: Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/[my-sub-guid]/resourceGroups/[my-app-res-group]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/[my-app-name]/config/appsettings?api-version=2019-08-01 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))
```

But the command work fine and publish the setting to the Azure except it publish not

```
PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name])
```

But

```
PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name]
```

Whats the problem with closing ) and what can I do to overcome this issue.

P.S. I know I can do this both from Azure Portal, Visual Studio and VS Code but it's critical for me to do this using commandline tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at this wiki around quoting issues with PowerShell:

- [Azure CLI - Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md)

To make it work you have few options:

1. Add additional double quotes for force powershell to treat the argument as a literal:

   ```
   az functionapp config appsettings set --name [my-app-name] --resource-group [my-app-res-group] --settings `""PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name])"`"
   ```
2. Use `--%` to stop PowerShell from parsing the argument and escape double quotes

   ```
   az --% functionapp config appsettings set --name [my-app-name] --resource-group [my-app-res-group] --settings "PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name])"
   ```

Comment: First option didn't work. But the second option worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Thomas's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655484/45375):

The problem comes down to two separate behaviors:

- The `az` CLI is implemented *as a batch file* (`az.cmd`)
- PowerShell - of necessity - *rebuilds* the command line that is passed to *external programs* (which includes batch files) *behind the scenes*.

  - In doing so, it uses `"..."` quoting (the only kind of quoting that external programs can be expected to understand) *on demand*: argument values are only enclosed in `"..."` *if they contain spaces*.

Unfortunately - and inappropriately - `cmd.exe` (the interpreter of batch files) evaluates the arguments passed to batch file *as if they had been submitted from inside a `cmd.exe` session*, which causes space-less arguments - which PowerShell passes *unquoted* - that happen to contain `cmd.exe` *metacharacters* (e.g, `&`) to be interpreted as such, breaking the command.

---

The **upshot** is: you need to **control the quoting used on the process command line *explicitly***:

- To **pass *verbatim* arguments to `az.cmd`**, you can use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) - though note its fundamental limitations, summarized in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375):

```
# Note the use of --% after --settings; only for *verbatim* arguments.
az functionapp config appsettings set --name [my-app-name] --resource-group [my-app-res-group] --settings --% "PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name])"
```

- **If you need *string  expansion (interpolation)***, i.e. if the arguments need to be expressed in terms of *PowerShell variables or expressions*, **call via `cmd.exe /c`**:

  - On the PowerShell side, an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) ensures that PowerShell variables (e.g., `$foo`) or expressions (e.g., `$(1 + 2)`) are interpolated; *embedded* `"` chars. must be escaped as `` `" ``

```
cmd /c "az functionapp config appsettings set --name [my-app-name] --resource-group [my-app-res-group] --settings `"PublicKey=@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=[vault-name];SecretName=[secret-name])`""
```

**Note**:

- **Using *direct invocation* with `` `""..."`" `` or `` "`"...`"" `` to ensure `"..."` enclosure on the resulting process command line *should never have worked***, and only works due to a long-standing bug - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).

  - While this bug was *mostly* fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7.3, the old, broken behavior is - unfortunately - *selectively retained* on Windows, notably when calling *batch files*.

    - See the [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing)
    - With respect to the *selective exceptions*, there is reason to believe that a never-ending game of catch-up will be played with respect to which external programs the exception will apply to - see [this comment on GitHub issue #18660](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18660#issuecomment-1327870905) - leaving aside that saddling future generations of PowerShell users with obscure, broken behavior was a bad idea to begin with; a crucial opportunity to make the breaking v7.3 change in a manner that eliminated historical baggage was missed  - see [this comment on GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143#issuecomment-833568832).
- The **advantage of the `cmd /c` approach is that it *predictably* works, irrespective of what external program you're calling**, and is therefore the preferable way to control the exact quoting *if and when needed*.