# Powershell: Stop-Parsing argument not working inside Braces

Tags: powershell

I have a need to check if a file has not been modified in XX minutes, and if condition is true, then kill the PID that has the file locked.
Only clean way to determine if a file has not been modified in XX minutes is in powershell but
Only way i have found to kill the associated PID locking the file is using handle OS command.
So, i am stuck with 1/2 batch and 1/2 powershell to accomplish what i want.

I have it working fine as a standalone command to kill the PID, but as soon as i put it all together inside braces, Powershell doesnt like it. Seems like it may not like putting the Stop-Parsing argument.
Code is below.. Calculating the $inactive variable earlier in the script. That part is fine. Its the cmd batch code that doesnt like being in curly braces.

```
if ($inactive -eq 'True') {cmd --% /C for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula file.csv') do taskkill /t /f /PID %i}
```

if i just run the cmd line inside powershell alone but without the {} it works fine, but i need to evaluate on the $inactive variable first to determine if i need to run the command

Works fine..

```
cmd --% /C for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula file.csv') do taskkill /t /f /PID %i
```

Doesnt work..

```
if ($inactive -eq 'True') {cmd --% /C for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula file.csv') do taskkill /t /f /PID %i}
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place the closing `}` *on the same line*, it isn't recognized as the block's closing delimiter (it is treated as part of the unparsed command line following `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)).

Place the `}` on the *next* line to fix the problem:

```sh
if ($inactive -eq 'True') {
  cmd --% /C for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula file.csv') do taskkill /t /f /PID %i
}
```

For more information on `--%`, including its limitations and pitfalls, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).