# Is there a way to output specific lines of code from a content using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, variables, github

I have used the code below to get all lines from content $ProjectFileContents that has "<PackageReference Include"

```
$ProjectFileContents | Find "<PackageReference Include" | Sort-Object -Unique
```

However when I try to get another line from the same content $ProjectFileContents that has "<OutputType", it returns an error

```
$ProjectFileContents | Find "<PackageReference Include" | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Error Gotten

```
Find : FIND: Parameter format not correct
At line:1 char:24
+ $ProjectFileContents | Find "OutputType" | Sort-Object -Unique
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (FIND: Parameter format not correct:String) [], 
RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I have used the same format I used initially however does not work for different set of strings. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!.

Comment: Escape the double-quotation marks so PowerShell passes them on to `find.exe` as-is: ```... |find `"<PackageReference Include`" | ...```

Comment: why are you using the `find.exe` util instead of staying with powershell code?

Comment: Why fall back on `find.exe`? Will this work? `($ProjectFileContents | Select-String -Pattern '<PackageReference Include').Line | Sort-Object`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) to satisfy `find.exe`'s specific quoting requirements.

```
$ProjectFileContents | find.exe --% "OutputType" | Sort-Object -Unique
```

---

As an aside: As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) recommends, consider a PowerShell-only solution, with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), which would bypass your problem.

The problem is that `find.exe` has very specific quoting requirements (which `findstr.exe` doesn't have, so it is another alternative to consider): The search term must *always* be enclosed in `"..."`, whether it contains spaces or other metacharacters or not.

However, when PowerShell rebuilds the command line to ultimately use *behind the scenes*, it only double-quotes *on demand*, so that a verbatim argument such as `OutputType` - because it contains *no spaces* - is passed as-is, without quoting - even if it was originally quoted in the *PowerShell* command.

`--%` tells PowerShell to retain the remaining arguments as-is, which preserves the `"..."` quoting - but do note that the remaining arguments mustn't contain variable references, as they wouldn't be expanded.

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375) for a detailed discussion of the limitations and pitfalls associated with `--%`