# Powershell Newman run pass --env-var as string

Tags: powershell, newman

Trying to run via powershell postman collection as following:

```
newman run $collPath -e $envPath $envVarsStr
```

where
`$envVarsStr` is a string containg N number dynamically generated --env-var
e.g.

```
--env-var "Base.Url=someurl" --env-var "Password=somepass"
```

But newman seems to ignore all my --env-vars
Using extra file is really not an option for me.

Any ideas on how to pass env-var string correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the [*stop parsing* operator](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-parsing.html). You can also use the invocation ("*call*" - `&`) operator as well.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala stop parsing is not an option since --env-var contains some powershell variable inside.
& is also not working for me `is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: @Abraham, `&` isn't needed here, because the executable name  (`newman`) is neither quoted nor contains variable references (you may use `& newman ...`, but it makes no difference). Use of `--%` is only an option if you define an _aux. environment variable_ that duplicates the `$envVarsStr` value and reference that instead. I've updated my answer to show this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass what an external program should see as *multiple* arguments via a *single string*, because **PowerShell passes a string as a *single* argument**, irrespective of the string's content.

Instead, **use an *array* of strings**, each element of which is passed as a separate argument.

Thus, if you control the creation of the arguments, use the following:

```sh
# Construct an array of arguments.
# Note: No *embedded* " quoting necessary - PowerShell will double-quote on demand.
$envVarsArgs = 
  '--env-var',
  'Base.Url=someurl', # use variables or expressions as needed
  '--env-var',
  'Password=somepass'
```

and then call `newman` as follows:

```sh
# Note: @envVarsArgs would work too.
newman run $collPath -e $envPath $envVarsArgs
```

---

**If you're *given* a single string encoding multiple arguments, you can split it into an array of individual arguments yourself**, which in the simplest case means:

```sh
newman run $collPath -e $envPath (-split $envVarsStr -replace '"')
```

However, this is *not* enough if any of the double-quoted substrings contain *spaces* (e.g. `--env-var "Foo=bar none"`), because the unary form of [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) splits by whitespace only.

---

**If you need to deal with a given string whose embedded quoted arguments *have spaces***,  you can use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) with an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in a pinch.

- Note: **`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be the *last resort*, due to its security risks**: only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

```sh
# !! See warning re Invoke-Expression above.
Invoke-Expression @"
newman run "$collPath" -e "$envPath" $envVarsStr
"@
```

<sup>Note the use of an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`), which simplifies embedded quoting (no need to escape the embedded `"` chars.)</sup>

**Another option is to use `--%`**, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), which, however, **requires you to define an *auxiliary environment variable*** that duplicates the value of your `$envVarsStr` variable:

- Note: **`--%` has many limitations** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

```sh
# Duplicate the string stored in $envVarsStr
# in an aux. environment variable, so it can be used with --%
$env:__aux = $envVarsStr

# Note the use of --% and the cmd.exe-style environment-variable
# reference:
newman run $collPath -e $envPath --% %__aux%
```

Comment: Invoke-Expression totally worked for me!