# Powershell and correctly quoting paths for command line tools

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have this program, Search everything, its a search tool. It has a command line tool that can be used to invoke a search without manually interacting with the GUI interface.

Its manual states that double quotes need to be escaped as well as paths  with spaces in them, [Command-line Options](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=10479):

> Use """ to escape a literal "
> For example, set the search to: "foo bar"
> Everything64.exe -s """"foo bar""""
> (Remember to also escape spaces with double quotes)

Paths with no spaces in them work just fine:

```
Everything64.exe -s c:\temp
```

[image]

```
Everything64.exe -s """C:\Program Files""""
```

[image]

The above attempt just inserts  a scrambled mixture of my users home and program files paths

I attemped to escape the double quotes with a backtick for every double quote, this just replaces all double quotes with back slashes :

```
Everything64.exe -s `"`"`"C:\Program Files`"`"`"
```

[image]

The same command line tool works just fine in command prompt.
[image]

EDIT 1:
My goal is to instead have `"C:\Program Files"`. the program accepts its own parameters in the GUI search bar, thus it requires that if the path has a space in it, it be quoted. This way search like`"C:\Program Files" !.jpg` means all files in folder accept `jpg` files.

---

I have searched and searched and cant arrive at what is causing this. I much prefer to stay in powershell and avoid cmd, please help

I have taken the liberty to cross post this question on other forums as well.

PSVersion 7.3.0-preview.7

Windows Terminal Preview 1.15.2003.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You only need to escape if you're needing to search for a literal double quote. Why aren't you simply doing `.\everything64.exe -s "C:\Program Files"` ??

Comment: Doing that inserts `C:\Program Files` in the programs search bar. My goal is to instead have `"C:\Program Files"`. the program accepts its own parameters in the GUI search bar, thus it requires that if the path has a space in it, it be quoted. This way search like`"C:\Program Files" !.jpg` means all files in folder accept `jpg` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for an external program such as `Everything64.exe` to see `"""C:\Program Files"""` on its command line, use the following, as of PowerShell 7.2.x:

```
Everything64.exe -s '"""C:\Program Files"""'
```

If you need to use `"..."` quoting in order to use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```
Everything64.exe -s "`"`"`"C:\Program Files`"`"`""
```

Note:

- This *shouldn't* work, but - serendipitously, in this case - *does* as of PowerShell 7.2.x, due to a long-standing bug, where `"` embedded in arguments passed to external programs aren't properly escaped - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).
- Thus, depending on how this bug is fixed in a future version, the above may break.

A future-proof - but limited - **alternative** is to use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) instead:

```
Everything64.exe -s --% """C:\Program Files"""
```

However, `--%` has fundamental limitations, notably not being able to incorporate PowerShell variables and expressions into the command - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).