# Using sed doesn't replace and there is no error too

Tags: windows, powershell, sed, escaping, quoting

I'm using Windows 10 x64, Powershell Core 7.2.6, and `/usr/bin/sed (GNU sed) 4.8` installed with Git for Windows. No WSL at all.

I have a `.env` file like this.

```
ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"
```

and I need to change it to:

```
ENDPOINT=""
```

So I'm using this powershell command:

```
sed -i -e 's/ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"/ENDPOINT=""/g' .env
```

but it doesn't change the file and there is no error at all.

If I use this instead it works:

```
sed -i -e 's/ENDPOINT/THIS_WORKS/g' .env
```

**Why?**

Maybe the issues are the `"` double quotes?

I tried with `" and "" too. No luck!

I tried the suggestion to use:

```
sed -i -e 's/ENDPOINT=\"localhost:3000\"/ENDPOINT=\"\"/g' .env
```

but it errors with:

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 67: unknown option to `s'
```

I also tried to reproduce the problem with:

```
'a', 'ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"', 'b' | sed -e 's/ENDPOINT=\"localhost:3000\"/ENDPOINT=\"\"/g'
```

The result is:

```
a                        
ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"
b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To work around a **long-standing PowerShell bug** present up to at least 7.2.x, **`"` chars. embedded in arguments passed to *external programs* must *manually*  be escaped as `\"`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)

  - The last two commands in your question *do* do that, which is *normally* enough, for *most* external CLIs.
- Additionally, *in your specific scenario* you need to work around a **quirk? bug? in the `sed.exe` implementation that ships with Git for Windows** by **ensuring that your `-e` argument (the `sed` script) *contains at least one (insignificant) space* (sic)**:

```bash
# Note the manually escaped " chars. (\") AND 
# the space right after the opening ' char.
# Result is now as expected: 'a', 'ENDPOINT=""', 'b'
'a', 'ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"', 'b' | 
  sed -e ' s/ENDPOINT=\"localhost:3000\"/ENDPOINT=\"\"/g'
```

The reason that the space makes a difference is that it causes PowerShell to enclose the argument in `"..."` behind the scenes when it builds the command line ultimately used for execution, which in the absence of spaces it does *not* do. Inexplicably, when the `sed.exe` implementation that comes with Git for Windows sees the  *unquoted* token `s/ENDPOINT=\"localhost:3000\"/ENDPOINT=\"\"/g` on its command line, it doesn't recognize it correctly, even though it should (it should be equivalent to the double-quoted form, `"s/ENDPOINT=\"localhost:3000\"/ENDPOINT=\"\"/g"`).

There are **alternative workarounds**:

- Bypass the problem with `"` characters by using a `sed` *escape sequence* to represent them instead, namely `\x22`:

  ```bash
  'a', 'ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"', 'b' |
    sed -e 's/ENDPOINT=\x22localhost:3000\x22/ENDPOINT=\x22\x22/g'
  ```
- Use `--%`, the [stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token) to explicitly control the quoting on the command line that `sed.exe` sees. *Caveat*: `--%` has significant limitations, notably the inability to (directly) incorporate PowerShell variables and expressions in the command - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

  ```bash
  # Note: Everything after --% is copied as-is to the command
  #       line used behind the scenes to invoke sed.exe
  'a', 'ENDPOINT="localhost:3000"', 'b' |
    sed -e --% "s/ENDPOINT=\"localhost:3000\"/ENDPOINT=\"\"/g"
  ```

Comment: You genius. It works amazingly well! The space after the `'` it's crazy! Thansk!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @FredHors; my pleasure. Learned something new as well.