# Trying to issue a curl POST command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl

I have been able to use curl to issue a query and return a result or series of named parameters.
I want to issue a POST command on these series of named parameters, but the "multiple" is tripping me up.
I can issue the POST command on one of the parameters, but not on the entire series of them.

The command I'm using within powershell is

```
curl.exe -u username:password -X POST http://site.url:8042/modalities/MCTEST/store -d '["6a3eb7c4-a9d83950-24d36e94-5c20d248-0b5ce989","8c93b430-757278ab-21ab643c-c98aa03d-da14148e","b8f648fa-175de243-de76b1c0-2dc7551a-928b86a5","c865b966-f0c7d2c2-0a1114e0-80531305-31cd104e","aac7f73f-fcb922ef-b950c4c1-ee1d512e-e2aeb5ae"]'
```

If I issue the command on only one, it processes fine...obviously, I don't need quotes or brackets, which I think is what is tripping me up.

```
curl.exe -u username:password -X POST http://site.url:8042/modalities/MCTEST/store -d 6a3eb7c4-a9d83950-24d36e94-5c20d248-0b5ce989
```

I've tried subbing the double quotes with a backslash, tried adding a backslash, I've tried everything i can think of...I'm missing something.

I get a response of "must provide a json value"
I'm not sure what my error is in my syntax.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

external commands have to be called/quoted properly

> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [Execution of External Commands in PowerShell Done Right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> [See also about Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)
>
> [Powershell: Pipe external command output to another external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220933/powershell-pipe-external-command-output-to-another-external-command)
>
> [How to use the curl command in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105458/how-to-use-the-curl-command-in-powershell)
>
> Stackoverflow example by Ansgar Wiechers

```
$CurlArgument = '-u', 'xxx@gmail.com:yyyy',
                '-X', 'POST',
                'https://xxx.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/abcd/efg/pull-requests/2229/comments',
                '--data', 'content=success'
$CURLEXE = 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe'
& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```