# tzutil - FIND: Parameter format not correct PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I am working with the PowerShell command. The following command gives parameter format error while executing to get timezone on specific `UTC`.

```
C:\Windows\system32\tzutil /l | find /I "utc-06"
```

> FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: Pipe external command output to another external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220933/powershell-pipe-external-command-output-to-another-external-command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find expects literal doublequotes.  You can also use findstr or select-string instead.

```
tzutil /l | find /i '"utc-06"'
tzutil /l | findstr /i utc-06
tzutil /l | select-string utc-06
```